# A series expansion for $\cot (\pi z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

How to show the following identity holds?

$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2z}{z^2-n^2}=\pi\cot \pi z-\dfrac{1}{z}\qquad |z|<1
$$

Comment: Search-engining "Herglotz Trick" will be interesting in this context.

Comment: Rasmus: Thanks for your information! I see it is in Chapter 23 of *Proofs From The Book* by Martin Aigner and Günter M. Ziegler.

Comment: many proofs appeared at SE : [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159752/proof-about-z-cot-z-1-2-sum-k-ge1z2-k2-pi2-z2), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495) and so on...

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped Américo. Cheers !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a link which deals with this problem: [people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf)

Comment: Why a negative vote! I don't Understand :x)

Comment: Maybe they are expecting you to give a short description of the content in the paper, instead of just citing it. Regards.