# Find the sum of $\sum \frac{1}{k^2 - a^2}$ when $0<a<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have been trying for a few days to figure out the sum of

$$ S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 - a^2} $$ where $a \in (0,1)$. So far from my nummerical
analysis and CAS that this sum equals

$$ S = \frac{1}{2a} \left[ \frac{1}{a} \, - \, \pi \cot(a\pi) \right] $$

But I have not been able to prove this yet. Anyone know how? My guess is that the 
sum of this series is related to fourier-series but nothing particalr comes to mind.

For the easy values, I have been able to use telescopic series, and a bit of algebraic magic, but for the general case I am stumpled. Anyone have any ideas or hints? Cheers.

Comment: There is the identity $$\frac{\sin\,\pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$ Take the logarithm, differentiate, see what happens.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Did you mean $k=1$ underneath the sum sign?

Comment: Yes he did, @Joel.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar your expected answer has an error. Checked against Wolfram Alpha's http://snipurl.com/23dq2hp and instead of plus sign, it shows minus sign. Follow J.M's hint, your might approach the answer.

Comment: You can use the residue theorem and contour integrals to do summations. Basically, if $f(z)$ decays fast enough as $z\rightarrow\infty$, $\sum f(n)=\sum Res(\pi f(z)\cot{\pi z})$. The same series (with a bit modification) is summed here http://www2.mae.ufl.edu/~uhk/SERIESCOMP.pdf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This question was settled in the Mathematics chatroom, but I'll put up the solution here for reference.

Starting with the infinite product

$$\frac{\sin\,\pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$

taking the logarithm of both sides gives

$$\log\left(\frac{\sin\,\pi x}{\pi x}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$

Differentiation gives

$$\frac{\pi x}{\sin\,\pi x}\left(\frac{\cos\,\pi x}{x}-\frac{\sin\,\pi x}{\pi x^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-2x}{k^2\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)}$$

which simplifies to

$$\pi\cot\,\pi x-\frac1{x}=-2x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2-x^2}$$

or

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2-x^2}=\frac1{2x^2}-\frac{\pi\cot\,\pi x}{2x}$$

Comment: While we are taking logarithm should'nt one be careful? i.e $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ can be negative real number for example. What branch are we considering?

Comment: @S.S "can be negative real number" - have you looked at a plot of $\dfrac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}$ for $0<x<1$ (cf. the title of this question)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that that the domain you were talking about was $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 35):

Let us consider the principal value of the conditionally convergent infinite harmonic series
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+k}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{1}{z+k}\tag{1a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z-k}+\frac{1}{z+k}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
The series in $(1c)$ converges absolutely for all non-integer $z$.

Each of the terms in $(1c)$ is odd, so $f(-z)=-f(z)$.

The series in $(1a)$ shows that $f$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at each integer.

$f$ has period $1$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(z+1)-f(z)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{1}{z+k+1}-\frac{1}{z+k}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{z+n+1}-\frac{1}{z-n}\\
&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$f(1/2)=0$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(1/2)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{1}{k+1/2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1/2}\\
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Take the derivative of $f$:
$$
f'(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{-1}{(z+k)^2}\tag{4}
$$
This series converges absolutely. and the terms monotonically go to $0$ as $|\Im(z)|\to\infty$.

Let's consider $if(iy)$ as $y\to\infty$. Using $(1c)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
if(iy)
&=\frac1y+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2y}{y^2+k^2}\\
&=\frac1y+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2/y}{1+(k/y)^2}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
As $y\to\infty$, the summation in $(5)$ is a Riemann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{2\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\pi\tag{6}
$$
Thus, $if(iy)\to\pi$ as $y\to\infty$ and $if(iy)\to-\pi$ as $y\to-\infty$.

Since $f$ has period $1$ and $f'(z)\to0$ as $|\Im(z)|\to\infty$, it is evident that $f(z)\to-i\pi$ as $\Im(z)\to\infty$ and $f(z)\to i\pi$ as $\Im(z)\to-\infty$. This means that $f$ is bounded when away from the real axis.

The functions $f$ and $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ have the same poles, with identical
residues, and both are bounded when away from the real axis.  Thus,
their difference is bounded for all $z$.  Since their difference is
analytic and bounded, it must be constant.  This difference is $0$ at
$1/2$, so it must be $0$ everywhere.  Therefore, the principal value of
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+k}=\pi\cot(\pi z)\tag{7}
$$
for all $z$.

---

Combining $(1c)$ and $(7)$ yields
$$
\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}=\pi\cot(\pi z)\tag{8}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2-z^2}
&=\frac{1}{2z^2}-\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{2z}\\
&=\frac{1}{2z}\left[\frac1z-\pi\cot(\pi z)\right]\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: A real approach is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077),

Answer (score 6):

You may prove this by expanding $\cos(zx)$ in Fourier series as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495).

This [paper](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf) could help too as well as articles in SE dealing with evaluation of $\zeta(n)$ with $n$ even.

Answer (score 3):

@Kobe found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064274) by means of residue calculus

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2 + a^2} = \frac{\pi\coth(\pi a)}{2a} - \frac{1}{2a^2}$$

To get your result, replace $a$ by $ia$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
S & \equiv \bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{1 \over k^{2} - a^{2}}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{k + 1 - a}\pars{k + 1 + a}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\Psi\pars{1 - a} - \Psi\pars{1 + a} \over -2a} =
{\Psi\pars{1 - a} - \bracks{\Psi\pars{a} + 1/a} \over -2a} 
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over -2a}\bracks{\pi\cot\pars{\pi a} - {1 \over a}} =
\bbx{{1 \over 2a}\bracks{{1 \over a} - \pi\cot\pars{\pi a}}}
\\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2-a^2}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k-a}-\frac{1}{k+a}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2 a} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k-a}+\frac{1}{-k-a}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2 a}\left[\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=-N}^N  \frac{1}{k-a}+\frac{1}{a}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{2 a}\left[\frac{1}{a}-\pi \cot (\pi a)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last  answer is given by the identity $\pi \cot (\pi x)=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=-N}^N \frac{1}{k+x}$, where $x \not\in\mathbb{Z}.$