# What is the value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{an^2+bn+c}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to evaluate the following alternating series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{an^2+bn+c}$$
I believe a closed form does exist, since there is one for [this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161259/what-would-be-the-value-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1an2bnc?noredirect=1).

I thought that one approach might be to factor the denominator in its two roots, and then rewrite using partial fractions. Now the two series obtained are of the form of [this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833264/generalization-of-alternating-harmonic-series?noredirect=1), and so there *is* a closed form, but the calculations get extremely messy after a few steps.

So I wonder, is there another method to get to a more pleasing closed form? Like the one in the first link?

Comment: [partial sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28-1%29%5En%2F%28a+n%5E2+%2B+b+n+%2B+c%29+for+n+from+1+to+infinity)

Comment: You can apply [your first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161259) to the two series ($n$ even, $n$ odd) of which yours is the difference.$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{an^2+bn+c}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(4a)k^2+(2b)k+c}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(4a)k^2+(4a+2b)k+c}$$