# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I am trying to find the pattern for the coefficients of the closed forms for this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2} \right)$$
The series seems to converge for every natural $k$, and it is easy to evaluate each of the two series using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178899/1174256), ending up with a bunch of digamma functions, as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29k%2Bn%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5D-Divide%5B1%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29k%2B1-n%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinf%7D%5D+). However, when plugging the series in wolfram for some values of $k$ this is what I got:
\begin{align}
k=1: &&& \frac{-5+2\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\pi\coth(\pi)}{4} \\
k=2: &&& \frac{-42-10\pi\tanh\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)+15\pi\coth(\pi)}{60} \\
k=3: &&& \frac{-341+120\pi\tanh\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)-90\pi\coth(2\pi)}{720} \\
k=4: &&& \frac{-3189-884\pi\tanh\left(\frac{5\pi}{2}\right)+1105\pi\coth(2\pi)}{8840} \\
k=5: &&& \frac{-58076+19890\pi\tanh\left(\frac{5\pi} {2}\right)-16575\pi\coth(3\pi)}{198900} \\
k=6: &&& \frac{-21576583-6277050\pi\tanh\left(\frac{7\pi}{2}\right)+7323225\pi\coth(3\pi)}{87878700}
\end{align}
The arguments of $\tanh$ and $\coth$ can be guessed, respectively, to $\frac{k+(k+1\mod2)}{2}\pi$ and $\frac{k+(k\mod2)}{2}\pi$, but the other coefficients are less easy to confront. The linear sequence in the numerators ($5,42,341,\dots$) does not appear even in the OEIS, and same goes for the denominators.

However, it is possible to guess the coefficients of $\tanh$ and $\coth$. Hence the question:

> How to show that
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2} \right)= \\
> =-\frac{a_k}{b_k}+\frac{\pi}{2k}\tanh\left(\frac{k}{2}\pi\right)-\frac{\pi}{2k+2}\coth\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\pi\right) \text{,} &&&  k\  \text{odd}\\
> =-\frac{a_k}{b_k}-\frac{\pi}{2k-2}\tanh\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\pi\right)+\frac{\pi}{2k}\coth\left(\frac{k}{2}\pi\right) \text{,} &&&  k\  \text{even}\\
> \end{align}
> and what are $a_k$ and $b_k$?

I know that, through residues, one can show that $$\frac{1}{k^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{\pi}{k\sinh(k\pi)}$$
and I believe something similar is going on here, though I am not able to see how.

Here are the most promising attempt so far:

Appearently the result in terms of digamma functions can be simplified a lot to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2} \right)=$$
$$=\frac{i}{2k}\left(\psi\left(1+\bar{z}k\right)-\psi\left(1+zk\right)\right)+\frac{i}{2(k+1)}\left(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)\right) \tag{*}$$
where $z=\frac{1+i}{2}$

I feel like **it is almost done**, but I can't perform the last steps to get rid of the digamma functions.
However, I strongly believe it has to do with the following two identities for $u\in \mathbb{C}$:
$$\psi(1-u)-\psi(u)=\pi\cot(\pi u) $$
$$\psi\left(\frac12+u\right)-\psi\left(\frac12-u\right)=\pi\tan(\pi u)$$

Any ideas on how to finish?

**EDIT**
I removed the other attempts since they were irrelevant.

Comment: Mathematica says: $\frac{i H_{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) k}}{2 k (k+1)}+\frac{i H_{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) k}}{2 (k+1)}-\frac{i H_{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) k}}{2 k
   (k+1)}-\frac{i H_{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) k}}{2 (k+1)}-\frac{i H_{\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) (k+1)}}{2 (k+1)}+\frac{i H_{\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)
   (k+1)}}{2 (k+1)}$ where H is Harmonic number.

Comment: You just have to figure out $a_k/d_k$ as $b_k/d_k$ and $c_k/d_k$ become readily apparent.

Comment: I think you'll kick yourself:  For $k=6$ there is $7323225\pi/87878700=\pi/12$.  Use `//Expand` on your *Mathematica* code.

Comment: oeis.org is your best friend for such things.

Comment: @JimB edited the question afetr your suggestions, thank you

Comment: The series will converge for any real $k$. Note that $\frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2}=\frac{(2k+1)(1-2n)}{\{(k+n)^2+n^2\}\{(k+1-n)^2+n^2\}}$, after which we can use the limit comparison theorem.

Comment: maybe not helpful, but looking at the just the $-\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ for odd $k$, it looks extremely close to $-c/k$ behavior for some constant $c$ when $k$ is large (just calculate more terms to really see it, I went out to $k=200$). It looks like $\frac{a_k}{b_k} \approx -\frac{\pi}{4k}$ for large $k$ but I have no way of defending this claim so don't put too much value in this.
you can see the plots here https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dtrimas/Published/looking_at_terms.nb

Comment: Just adding on to my previous comment: for odd n it should be $\frac{a_k}{b_k} \approx -\frac{\pi }{2 (k+1)}$ because I forgot I was using $k$ as an index list of odd terms and not all the integer values

Comment: @ydd I read your document, I find it very interesting. Did you spot anything similar for the even $k$ as well? Also, from what you wrote I first thought $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ must be something like $-\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{A(k)}{B(k)}$ where $A(k)\simeq B(k)$ as $k\to\infty$, for instance $A(k)=n^2+2n$, $B(k)=n^2-3n+1$ (just random numbers to get the idea). But then I realized that $a_k$ and $b_k$ are always integer! How could this be? I couldn't think of a way to write $A(k)$,$B(k)$ such that the $\pi$ gets canceled at every $k$ and appears only in the limit.

Comment: @Zima good to hear. I made some changes to the document regarding the mistake I made with $\frac{\pi}{4k}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}$. I could just be wrong about the limit value of $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ being $-\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}$ for odd $k$. It could be some rational close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead. I also agree that it sounds difficult, maybe even not possible, to find a rational function $\frac{A(k)}{B(k)}$ that cancels the pi term at all odd integers, and satisifies $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{A(k)}{B(k)} = \frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ (with $\frac{a_k}{b_k} = -\pi \frac{A(k)}{B(k)} $).

Comment: I have not looked at the even $k$ terms yet but might be able to later.

Comment: I had a suspicion that my expression $\frac{a_k}{b_k}\approx -\frac{\pi}{2k+1} \approx -\frac{\pi}{2k}$ for large $k$ was just the first order expansion of the sum as $k \rightarrow \infty$ and this appears to be true. The series expansion of 
$$\frac{i}{2k}\left(\psi\left(1+\bar{z}k\right)-\psi\left(1+zk\right)\right)+\frac{i}{2(k+1)}\left(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)\right) $$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$ is $-\frac{\pi }{2 k}+\frac{3 \pi }{4 k^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^3\right)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I finally did it!**

What follows is the process that leads to the final result in terms of hyperbolic functions. Plus, two additional very interesting **side-results**.

I will start from the formula in $(\text{*})$: for $z=\frac{1+i}{2}$ the following holds
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{(k+n)^2+n^2}-\frac{1}{(k+1-n)^2+n^2} \right)=$$

$$=\frac{i}{2k}\left(\psi\left(1+\bar{z}k\right)-\psi\left(1+zk\right)\right)+\frac{i}{2(k+1)}\left(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)\right)$$

and then work my way through the cancelation of the digamma functions.

**Tools:**

The main tools we are going to use are the following:
$$\psi(1+u)=\psi(u)+\frac{1}{u} \tag{1}$$
$$\psi(1-u)-\psi(u)=\pi\cot(\pi u) \tag{2} $$
$$\psi(u+k)=\psi(u)+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{u+n}\tag{3}$$
$$\psi(-u)=\psi(u)+\frac1u+\pi\cot(\pi u)\tag{4}$$
Now, for reference purpose, let's name
$$\color{red}{S_1}=\frac{i}{2k}\left(\psi\left(1+\bar{z}k\right)-\psi\left(1+zk\right)\right) \hspace{1cm} \color{blue}{S_2}=\frac{i}{2(k+1)}\left(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)\right)$$
and let's start with $S_1$.

**PART $1$: $S_1$**

It all starts by noticing that since $z=\frac{1+i}{2}$, we have that $\bar{z}=1-z$, therefore:
\begin{align}
\psi(1+\bar{z}k)-\psi(1+zk)&=\psi(1+k-zk)-\psi(1+zk) \\
&\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=}\psi(1+k-zk)-\psi(zk)-\frac{1}{zk} \\
&\stackrel{\text{(3)}}{=}\psi(1-zk)+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{1-zk+n}-\psi(zk)-\frac{1}{zk} \\
&\stackrel{\text{(2)}}{=}\pi\cot(\pi zk)+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{1-zk+n}-\frac{1}{zk} \\
\end{align}
Next, plug $z$ in and simplify:
$$\frac{1}{zk}=\frac1k-\frac{i}{k}$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1-zk}=\frac{2}{2n+2-(1+i)k}=\frac{4n+4-2k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}+i\frac{2k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}$$
$$\cot(\pi zk)=\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1+i)k\right)=-\frac{\sin(k\pi)}{\cos(k\pi)-\cosh(k\pi)}+i\frac{\sinh(k\pi)}{\cos(k\pi)-\cosh(k\pi)}$$
and finally, putting these values back in $S_1$, together with the fact that $\sin(k\pi)=0$ and $\cos(k\pi)=(-1)^k$, we get
\begin{align}
\color{red}{S_1}&=\frac{i}{2k}(\psi(1+\bar{z}k)-\psi(1+zk)) \\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2k}\frac{\sinh(k\pi)}{(-1)^k-\cosh(k\pi)}-\frac{1+i}{2k^2}+\frac{i}{k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2} \\
\end{align}
And now, since the original series was always real, we can extract the real part and leave the result unchanged! Therefore
$$\boxed{\color{red}{S_1}=-\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{\pi}{2k}\frac{\sinh(k\pi)}{(-1)^k-\cosh(k\pi)}-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}}$$
Additionally, since the result is real, then the imaginary part is $0$, and this leads to the first **side-result**:
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{2n+2-k}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2}=\frac{1}{2k}}$$
Now that we are done with $S_1$, let's attack $S_2$.

**PART $2$: $S_2$**

Remember that
$$\color{blue}{S_2}=\frac{i}{2(k+1)}(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk))$$
As before, we will start by using the fact that $\bar{z}=1-z$:
\begin{align}
\psi(z-\bar{z}k) & =\psi(z-k+zk) \\
& \stackrel{\text{(4)}}{=}\psi(-z+k-zk)+\frac{1}{k-z-zk}+\pi\cot(\pi(k-z-zk)) \\
& \stackrel{\text{(3)}}{=}\psi(-z-zk)+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n-z-zk}+\frac{1}{k-z-zk}+\pi\cot(\pi(k-z-zk)) \\
\end{align}
while for the second digamma:
\begin{align}
\psi(\bar{z}-kz) & =\psi(1-z-zk) \\
& \stackrel{\text{(1)}}{=}\psi(-z-zk)-\frac{1}{z+zk} \\
\end{align}
and therefore
$$\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)=\frac{1}{k-z-zk}+\frac{1}{z+zk}+\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{n-z-zk}+\pi\cot(\pi(k-z-zk))$$
Again, plug $z$ in and simplify:
$$\frac{1}{k-z-zk}=\frac{2}{k-ik-(1+i)}=\frac{k-1}{k^2+1}+i\frac{k+1}{k^2+1}$$
$$\frac{1}{z+zk}=\frac{1}{1+k}-i\frac{1}{1+k}$$
$$\frac{1}{n-z-zk}=-\frac{k-2n+1}{n^2+(n-1)^2-2kn+k^2+2k}+i\frac{k+1}{n^2+(n-1)^2-2kn+k^2+2k} $$
$$\cot(\pi(k-z-zk))=-\frac{\sin(k\pi)}{\cos(k\pi)-\cosh((k+1)\pi)}+i\frac{\sinh((k+1)\pi)}{\cos(k\pi)-\cosh((k+1)\pi)}$$
and now, putting these values back in $S_2$, we end up with
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{S_2} & =\frac{i}{2(k+1)}(\psi(z-\bar{z}k)-\psi(\bar{z}-zk)) \\
& =\frac{i}{2}\frac{k-1}{(k+1)(k^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2(k^2+1)}+\frac{1+i}{2(k+1)^2}-\frac{i}{2(k+1)}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{k-2n+1}{(k-n+1)^2+n^2}-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(k-n+1)^2+n^2}-\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}\frac{\sinh((k+1)\pi)}{(-1)^k-\cosh((k+1)\pi)}
\end{align}
but again, $S_2$ is real! So extracting the real part leads us to the final value for $S_2$:
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{S_2}=\frac{1}{2(k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(k^2+1)}-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(k-n+1)^2+n^2}-\frac{\pi}{2(k+1)}\frac{\sinh((k+1)\pi)}{(-1)^k-\cosh((k+1)\pi)}}$$
And, for the second **side-result**, just take the imaginary part and set it equal to $0$:
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{k-2n+1}{(k-n+1)^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{k-1}{k^2+1}}$$

**Conclusion:**

Finally, remember that we were after $\color{red}{S_1}+\color{blue}{S_2}$, and notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{\sinh(x)}{(-1)^k-\cosh(x)} & =-\coth\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \hspace{1cm}\text{k even} \\
& =-\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \hspace{1cm}\text{k odd} \\
\end{align}
which shows why in the conjectured form there are only $\tanh$ and $\coth$.
Furthermore, if I haven't made any typo, we now have an expression for the ratio $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$:
\begin{align}
\color{green}{\frac{a_k}{b_k}} & =\frac{1}{2(k+1)^2}-\frac{1}{2(k^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(k-n+1)^2+n^2}-\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(2n+2-k)^2+k^2} \\
\end{align}
and I have checked that this agrees with the first few cases. This ugly representation also explains why the two sequences $a_k$, $b_k$ were so hard to guess. It remains to check if this is consistent with @Ydd's result for $\frac{a_k}{b_k}$ as $k\to\infty$, but honestly I can't see how to do it now.

Out of all of this, what I find most intriguing are the two closed forms for the sums obtained setting $\Im=0$.