# Partial Fractions Expansion of $\tanh(z)/z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, partial-fractions

I have seen the following formula in papers (without citations) and in [Mathematica's documentation about `Tanh[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tanh.html):

$$
\frac{\tanh(z)}{8z}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2 \pi^2+4z^2}
$$

I have no idea how to prove it and I have also encountered in my research similar sums involving, for instance, $\mathrm{coth}$. It would be nice to have a general method for working with these problems; any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can try the Taylor Series?

Comment: As noted, you should consult a textbook in complex analysis.  Usually you will see this as a series for $\tan z$, and then a simple change of variables $iz$ will give you a similar one for $\tanh z$.

Comment: [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.10.E25)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the [infinite product representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.36.E2)

$$\cosh\,z=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2k-1)^2}\right)$$

Taking logarithms gives

$$\log\cosh\,z=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2k-1)^2}\right)$$

If we differentiate both sides, we have

$$\tanh\,z=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{8z}{\pi^2(2k-1)^2}}{1+\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2k-1)^2}}$$

which simplifies to

$$\tanh\,z=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{8z}{4z^2+\pi^2(2k-1)^2}$$

Note that the infinite product that we started with is the factorization of $\cosh$ over its (imaginary) zeroes.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470) is a related question.

Comment: @jm this is great; does all such formulas rely on manipulating other known products and sums? Isn't there, for instance, a Fourier transform or generating function approach (or something...)?  Again, thank you for the support.

Comment: Well, the more systematic route uses polygamma functions/generalized harmonic numbers, but I thought you'd prefer the route that doesn't require special functions. This is the easiest route I know for the tangent, cotangent, and their hyperbolic counterparts.

Comment: Yeah. Probably. Hehe. It's just that I never know how to deal with sums in any other way than comparing it to other sums. Again, thank you for the answer J.M.

Comment: Our answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1) seem to be paralleled here :-)

Comment: @rob, hence the upvote. ;)

Answer (score 7):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179), it is shown that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}\tag{1}
$$
Applying the identity $\tan(x)=\cot(x)-2\cot(2x)$ to $(1)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\tan(\pi z)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2z}{z^2-\frac{k^2}{4}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{8z}{4z^2-(2k)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{8z}{4z^2-k^2}\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{8z}{4z^2-(2k-1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{8z}{(2k-1)^2-4z^2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Applying the identity $\tanh(x)=-i\tan(ix)$ to $(2)$ yields
$$
\pi\tanh(\pi z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{8z}{(2k-1)^2+4z^2}\tag{3}
$$
Finally, applying the change variables $z\mapsto z/\pi$ to $(3)$ reveals
$$
\frac{\tanh(z)}{8z}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2\pi^2+4z^2}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: how did you get equation $(2)$ from the series sum?

Comment: @Danny: I've added a couple of lines of explanation. First, we multiply numerator and denominator by $4$. Then note that we are subtracting the terms $\frac{8z}{4z^2-j^2}$ with both even and odd $j$ from the terms with only even $j$. That leaves the negative of the terms with odd $j$.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to find such expansions is a technique based on expanding a meromorphic function in terms of rational fractions by exploiting its poles. A theorem related to this work is called the Mittag-Leffler theorem in complex analysis. See [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB&pli=1) (starting from page (96)).
You can find examples of such expansions for the functions $\tan(z)\,,\sec(z)\, \cot(z)\,, \csc(z) \,. $

Comment: For a somewhat less obscene reference on Mittag-Leffler theorem, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem).

Comment: I reffered the OP where he can find the techniques and examples to his question. It is in the heart of my research.

Comment: I cannot open that link(starting from page (96)) it says you need permission.