# Integral $\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Greetings I saw  [here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/User:Integrals123) (among the last integrals) that: $$\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=\pi C$$
Where $C$ is Catalan's constant. Did this integral appear here before? (my quick search did not found anything).

I gave it a try and got stuck. Denoting the integral as $I$ and using that $\ln \left(\frac ab\right)=\ln a- \ln b\ $ we have: $$I=K(1,1)-K(1,-1)-K(-1,1)+K(-1,-1)$$ Where $$K(a,b)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+ax)\ln(1+bx^2)}{x}dx$$ Differentiating under the integral sign: $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}K(a,b)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{(1+ax)(1+bx^2)}\,dx$$ By partial fractions we get: $$\frac{1}{a^2+b}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{ax}{bx^2+1}\,dx -\int_0^1 \frac{1}{bx^2+1}\,dx +\int_0^1 \frac{1}{ax+1} \,dx\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{a^2+b}\left(\frac{a\ln(1+b)}{2b}-\frac{\arctan \left(\sqrt b\right)}{\sqrt{b}} +\frac{\ln(1+a)}{a}\right) $$ And now since $K(0,b)=K(a,0)=0$ $$K(a,b)=\frac12\int_0^a \int_0^b \frac{x\ln(1+y)}{y(x^2+y)}\,dy\,dx-\int_0^a \int_0^b \frac{\arctan \left(\sqrt y\right)}{\sqrt{y}(x^2+y)}\,dy\,dx +\int_0^a \int_0^b \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x(x^2+y)}\,dy\,dx$$  Is there a clever way to solve this?
Another way is to start by using: $$-\frac12\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ $$I=4\sum_{n,k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2k+1)}\int_0^1 x^{4n+2k+2}\,dx=4\sum_{n,k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2k+1)(4n+2k+3)}$$ But I dont know how to deal with this series. I would appreciate some help with this integral!

Comment: It has in fact appeared here before, in a disguise: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582943/integral-int-0-infty-frac-tanh2xx2dx/1617110#1617110

Comment: Oh, thats nice, why not add an answer for $s=2$ using that?  because it seems like you avoided there exactly this particular integral :( Also is there any reasons that Catalan's constant doesnt appear in other integrals?

Comment: That's because the case $s=2$ was discussed in the link in the comments ("done by @M.N.C.E" etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the integrand is an even function, we can write

$$ I
= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x}. $$

Now deforming the line contour $[-1, 1]$ to the semicircular contour from $-1$ to $1$ and substituting $x = e^{i\theta}$,

$$ I = -\frac{i}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \log(-i\tan(\theta/2)) \log(-i\tan \theta) \, d\theta, $$

where we utilized the identity $\frac{1-e^{i\theta}}{1+e^{i\theta}} = -i\tan(\theta/2)$. Now we note that, for $\theta \in (0, \pi/2) \cup (\pi/2, \pi)$,

- $\log(-i\tan(\theta/2)) = \log\tan(\theta/2) - \frac{i\pi}{2}$,
- $\log(-i\tan\theta) = \log\lvert\tan\theta\rvert - \operatorname{sign}(\tan\theta)\frac{i\pi}{2}$.
- $\int_{0}^{\pi} \log\lvert\tan\theta\rvert \, d\theta = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\log\sin\theta - \log\cos\theta) \, d\theta = 0$.

Plugging these back and taking real parts only (since we know that $I$ is real),

\begin{align*}
I
&= -\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( \log\lvert\tan\theta\rvert + \operatorname{sign}(\tan\theta)\log\tan(\theta/2) \right) \, d\theta \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \log\tan(\theta/2) \, d\theta \\
&= -\pi \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log u}{1+u^2} \, du, \qquad (u=\tan(\theta/2)) \\
&= \pi C.
\end{align*}

---

**Generalization.** Utilizing a similar idea s in the computation above, we can prove that

> **Proposition.** Let $p$, $q$ be positive integers. Write $g = \gcd(p,q)$ and assume that $p/g$ and $q/g$ are not simultaneously odd. Then
>
> \begin{align*}
> &\int_{0}^{1} \log\left(\frac{1-x^p}{1+x^p}\right)\log\left(\frac{1-x^q}{1+x^q}\right)\,\frac{dx}{x} \\
> &\hspace{6em} = \pi \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} \left( \frac{1}{p}\tan\left((2n+1)\frac{\pi p}{2q}\right) + \frac{1}{q} \tan\left((2n+1)\frac{\pi q}{2p}\right)\right)
> \end{align*}

Of course, the above can be simplified further by using either [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) or [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)
.

Comment: Wonderful! But what does it mean (or happen) when  the line contour gets deformed to the semicircular one?

Comment: @Dahaka, It requires a bit of knowledge on complex analysis. Suppose that we have a [*differentiable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) function $f:U\underset{\text{open}}{\subseteq}\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ and two curves $\alpha, \beta \subset U$ which starts at $a$ and ends at $b$. Then we have $$\int_{\alpha}f(z)\,dz=\int_{\beta}f(z)\,dz$$ as long as one can continuously deform $\alpha$ to $\beta$ within the region $U$ while fixing two endpoints $a$ and $b$. In our example, the line from $1$ to $-1$ can be continuously deformed to the semicircle from $1$ to $-1$.

Comment: (I cheated a bit here, since $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)\log\left(\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}\right)$ fails to be differentiable at $1, i, -1$. But this issue can be resolved by an appropriate limiting argument.)

Answer (score 6):

It's always the same story,

$$J=\int_0^1 \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x}$$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,

$$
J =2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)\ln x}{x^2-1}\,dx
$$

For $x\in [0;1]$ define the function $R$,

\begin{align}R(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{t^2-1}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln( tx)}{t^2x^2-1}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Observe that $R(0)=0$.

\begin{align}J = {} & 2\left[R(x)\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)\right]_0^1-2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)\ln(tx)}{(x^2+1)(t^2x^2-1)}\,dt\,dx\\
= {} & -2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)\ln(tx)}{(x^2+1)(t^2x^2-1)}\,dt\,dx\\
= {} & -2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)\ln t}{(x^2+1)(t^2x^2-1)}\,dt\,dx-2\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)\ln x}{(x^2+1)(t^2x^2-1)}\,dt\,dx\\
= {} & \int_0^1\left[\frac{1-t^2}{t(1+t^2)}\ln\left(\frac{1+tx}{1-tx}\right)-\frac{4\arctan x}{t^2+1}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\ln t\,dt-{}\\
&\int_0^1 \left[\frac{1-x^2}{x(1+x^2)}\ln\left(\frac{1+tx}{1-tx}\right)\right]_{t=0}^{t=1}\ln x\,dx\\
= {} & 4\times \frac{\pi}{4}\times -\int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\\
= {} & \boxed{\pi\text{G}}
\end{align}

$\text{G}$ is the Catalan constant.

PS:
The idea is always the same, rewrite the integral as  $\displaystyle \int_0^1 A(x)\ln x\ln(B(x))\,dx$, $A,B$ rational fraction functions. Then consider $\displaystyle R(x)=\int_0^x A(t)\ln t\,dt$ and finally perform integration by parts. If you know that the result is not too complicated you're pretty sure the process will work ;)

PS2:
Actually, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 A(x)\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\beta_n\ln(B_n(x))+\sum_{n=1}^M \delta_n \arctan(C_n(x))\right)\,dx$ with $\beta_n,\delta_n$ real numbers, $A,B_n,C_n$ rational fractional function will work too if the result is supposed to be not too complicated.
(see [Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x \log x}{1+x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842284/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-log-x1xdx/1842492#1842492) for another miraculous evaluation of integral. )

Comment: Thank you! This looks impressive, im not so flexible with switching to double integrals so let me try to understand and re-do it myself for a few days.

Comment: Dahaka: don't be afraid of double integrals, I suck at computing them. I use only Fubini's theorem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: $$ J =2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)\ln x}{x^2-1}\,dx$$ When you have a line with nothing on it except what is shown above, why do you use \displaystyle instead of an actual display? (I changed it when I edited your answer.) $\qquad$

Comment: Maybe cause i suck at writing Latex. Thanks anyway.