# Integrals $\int \frac{1}{\operatorname{arctanh}(x)} \, dx$ and $\int \frac{1}{\operatorname{arccoth}(x)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Do we know anything about this integrals?

$$
\begin{align}
I_1(x) = \int \frac{1}{\operatorname{artanh}(x)} \, dx \\
I_2(x) = \int \frac{1}{\operatorname{arcoth}(x)} \, dx
\end{align}$$

Similar integrals.

$$
\begin{align}
\int \operatorname{artanh}(x) \, dx & = x \operatorname{artanh}(x) + \frac12 \ln(1-x^2) + C, \\
\int \operatorname{arcoth}(x) \, dx & = x \operatorname{arcoth}(x) + \frac12 \ln(1-x^2) + C, \\
\int \frac{1}{\operatorname{arsinh}(x)} \, dx & = \operatorname{Chi}(\operatorname{arsinh}(x)) + C, \\
\int \frac{1}{\operatorname{arcosh}(x)} \, dx & = \operatorname{Shi}(\operatorname{arcosh}(x)) + C, \\
\end{align}$$

where $\operatorname{Chi}$ is the  [hyperbolic cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html), and $\operatorname{Shi}$ is the [hyperbolic sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html).

I found nothing with *Maple* or *Mathematica*. As I see some kind of "hyperbolic tangent integral" is not defined.

Comment: Note: the prefix for inverse hyperbolic functions is $\rm{ar}$, **not** $\rm{arc}$ (which is for inverse trig. functions).

Comment: @alexqwx As you wish. By the way also note that computer algebra systems use arctanh instead of artanh. For example [`arctanh`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=invtrig) in *Maple* or [`ArcTanh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTanh.html) in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @user153012 This is because *arc* refers to the arc that the given angle subtends on the unit circle. On the unit hyperbola, there is no direct relationship between the inverse hyperbolic functions with the subtended angle, but (as in the trigonometric setting) there *is* a relationship with the area bounded by the $x$-axis, the arc of the hyperbola and the segment connecting the origin with the reference point on the hyperbola.

Answer (score 3):

Approach $1$:

For $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{arcoth }x}dx$ ,

Let $u=\text{arcoth }x$ ,

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{arcoth }x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{u}d(\coth u)$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\int\coth u~d\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\dfrac{\coth u}{u^2}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\dfrac{e^{2u}+1}{u^2(e^{2u}-1)}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\int\dfrac{1}{u^2(e^{-2u}-1)}du+\int\dfrac{1}{u^2(e^{2u}-1)}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\int\dfrac{1}{u^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_n(-2u)^{n-1}}{n!}du+\int\dfrac{1}{u^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{B_n(2u)^{n-1}}{n!}du$ (with the formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function)

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n2^{n-1}B_nu^{n-3}}{n!}du+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{n-1}B_nu^{n-3}}{n!}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^nB_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\left(\dfrac{1}{u^3}+\dfrac{1}{3u}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{4^nB_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}\right)du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\dfrac{1}{2u^2}+\dfrac{\ln u}{3}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n-1}B_{2n}u^{2n-2}}{(2n)!(n-1)}+C$

$=\dfrac{x}{\text{arcoth }x}-\dfrac{1}{2~\text{arcoth}^2x}+\dfrac{\ln\text{arcoth }x}{3}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n-1}B_{2n}\text{arcoth}^{2n-2}x}{(2n)!(n-1)}+C$

For $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{artanh }x}dx$ ,

Let $u=\text{artanh }x$ ,

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{artanh }x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{u}d(\tanh u)$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}-\int\tanh u~d\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\dfrac{\tanh u}{u^2}du$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\dfrac{1}{u^2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)B_{2n}u^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}du$ (with the formula in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions)

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)B_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}du$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\left(\dfrac{1}{u}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)B_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}\right)du$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\ln u+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n-1}(4^n-1)B_{2n}u^{2n-2}}{(2n)!(n-1)}+C$

$=\dfrac{x}{\text{artanh }x}+\ln\text{artanh }x+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n-1}(4^n-1)B_{2n}\text{artanh}^{2n-2}x}{(2n)!(n-1)}+C$

Approach $2$:

For $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{arcoth }x}dx$ ,

Let $u=\text{arcoth }x$ ,

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{arcoth }x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{u}d(\coth u)$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\int\coth u~d\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\dfrac{\coth u}{u^2}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}+\int\dfrac{1}{u^3}+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{u(u^2+n^2\pi^2)}du$ (use [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem#Pole_expansions_of_meromorphic_functions) of hyperbolic cotangent)

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\dfrac{1}{2u^2}+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2}{n^2\pi^2u}du-\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2u}{n^2\pi^2(n^2\pi^2+u^2)}du$

$=\dfrac{\coth u}{u}-\dfrac{1}{2u^2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{2\ln u}{n^2\pi^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\ln(n^2\pi^2+u^2)}{n^2\pi^2}+C$

$=\dfrac{\ln\text{arcoth }x}{3}+\dfrac{x}{\text{arcoth }x}-\dfrac{1}{2(\text{arcoth }x)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\ln(n^2\pi^2+(\text{arcoth }x)^2)}{n^2\pi^2}+C$

For $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{artanh }x}dx$ ,

Let $u=\text{artanh }x$ ,

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{\text{artanh }x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{u}d(\tanh u)$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}-\int\tanh u~d\left(\dfrac{1}{u}\right)$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\dfrac{\tanh u}{u^2}du$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8}{u((2n+1)^2\pi^2+4u^2)}du$ (use [Mittag-Leffler Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem#Pole_expansions_of_meromorphic_functions) of [hyperbolic tangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175863))

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2u}du-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{32u}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2((2n+1)^2\pi^2+4u^2)}du$

$=\dfrac{\tanh u}{u}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{8\ln u}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4\ln((2n+1)^2\pi^2+4u^2)}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}+C$

$=\ln\text{artanh }x+\dfrac{x}{\text{artanh }x}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4\ln((2n+1)^2\pi^2+4(\text{artanh }x)^2)}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}+C$

Comment: With some help from *Mathematica* I get
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{4^nB_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}=\frac{3u\coth(u)-u^2-3}{3u^3}.$$
But I don't know, how to integrate it. It leads to the integral $\int \frac{1}{\left(e^{2 u}-1\right) u^2} \, du$.

Comment: @user153012: Sorry, I have some typo of some cofficients. I corrected.

Comment: Harry, maybe you can use the following.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{4^n(4^n-1)B_{2n}u^{2n-3}}{(2n)!}=\frac{2u\coth(2u)-u \coth(u)-u^2}{u^3‌​}.$$