# A cute approximation for $\cot(2\pi x)$(!?)

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, bernoulli-numbers

Numerical calculations and some theory leads to the suggestion that

$$\cot(2\pi x) \rightarrow\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_r \frac{1}{x-r}$$

where $r$ ranges over all the roots of $B_{2n+1}$ (Bernoulli polynomial) as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Does this converge to $\cot(2\pi x)$? If so, how fast? Do you have pointers to books, articles?

Here is one article that is relevant for a start:

[Uniform Convergence Behavior of the Bernoulli Polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703452)

The theory behind it is really just Corollary 2.1, page 3 from that article and that for

$P(x)$ and $Q(x) = (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2) \cdots (x-\alpha_n)$ polynomials $\textrm{deg }P < \textrm{deg }Q$, $\alpha_i$ distinct, then

$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P(\alpha_i)}{Q'(\alpha_i)}\frac{1}{(x-\alpha_i)}$$ [partial fractions Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Procedure) (also $B_n'(x)=nB_{n-1}(x))$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another series expansion which results from exploiting the poles of $\cot(x)$,

$$ \cot(x)= \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{{k=-\infty}_{k\neq0}}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{x-k\pi}+ \frac{1}{k\pi}  \right). $$

For more details on the method, see [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB) starting from page $101$.

Comment: Actually, this the sum above equals $\cot(x)-\frac1x$. Note that when $x=0$, the sum is $0$. The formula that I have found very useful is
$$
\pi\cot(\pi z)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{z+k}
$$
where the sum is taken in the principal value sense. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179)

Comment: However, this does not answer the question as your sum is over the integers and the question asks about the sum over the roots of the Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: @robjohn: I just missed $\frac{1}{x}$ when I was typing the answer. Thanks.