# why $\pi \cot \pi z = \sum _{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z+n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

In prove of the above claim I need  prove:
$\cot (\pi\cdot z)$
is bounded for $\{y \geq 1 , 0.5 \geq x \geq -0.5\}$
In stein book a function has defined: 
$$\Delta ( z ) = \pi \cot \pi z -  \sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$$
It has proved that  $\Delta ( z ) $ is entire and it's  sufficient to $\Delta ( z ) $  be abounded.

Comment: The content and title are asking for separate things, which one is the question?

Comment: What has to do what you ask with what you say you have to prove, anyway? Can you give some background, ideas, self effort, etc.?

Comment: Well, you changed completely the question, yet there still remains one doubt: what has to do *the proof* of the equality in the title with the boundness of $\,\cot \pi z\,$ wherever? Couldn't it be that you need to prove the equality *and then using it* you have to prove the boundness?

Comment: Can you exhibit a value of $z$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z^2}{n^2})$ converges?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen for all $z \notin \mathbb{Z}$  it converges.

Comment: The expression in the - now modified - title may converge as $\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac1{z+n}=\frac 1z+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}$. But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z^2}{n^2})$ (occuring in the definition of $\Delta$ and in the original question title) will *never* converge as the summands tend to $1$

Comment: You're right. I write it wrong and edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the boundedness away from the real axis,
$$
\begin{align}
|\cot(\pi z)|
&=\left|\frac{e^{i\pi z}+e^{-i\pi z}}{e^{i\pi z}-e^{-i\pi z}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{e^{i\pi x-\pi y}+e^{-i\pi x+\pi y}}{e^{i\pi x-\pi y}-e^{-i\pi x+\pi y}}\right|\\
&\le\frac{e^{\pi|y|}+e^{-\pi|y|}}{e^{\pi|y|}-e^{-\pi|y|}}\\[6pt]
&=\coth(\pi|y|)
\end{align}
$$
which decreases monotonically to $1$ as $|y|\to\infty$.

For the question in the title, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179).