# Curious $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 - x^2}$ identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, zeta-functions

Let $$F(x) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 - x^2}$$

It seems that for odd integer $k$ $$F\left(\frac{k}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{k^2}$$
My evidence is strictly computational, and I have no idea how to approach a proper proof. So standard questions are:

- is it a known fact
- is it a fact
- is it curious
- what is a proof strategy

Please advise.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2 and put $a= ix$

Comment: Or more directly the question [141470](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1)