# How to evaluate the summation $S_b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

This question is from my notebook, not hw or else, only exercise to understand better. I tried by myself. However, since my trail are too trivial, I dont need to write here. i am confused a bit. I want to learn how to solve such question types. I guess I need to use residue. I am grateful to help me thank you.

[image]

Comment: i'm sure it's a duplicate i've seen it berfore .

Comment: Reall? I dont know there exists its dublicate, If I knew, I didnt post it. Please if you see its dublicate and its solution is explanatory and clear, can you send its link? Thank you @what'sup

Comment: ok just a minute many other guys will help you too

Comment: If you are interest in complex analysis,please can you explain its solution below answer box in a clear way? @what'sup

Comment: Okay thank you :) @what'sup

Comment: i can help you but i think there was the way you want in the another question .

Comment: download chapter 11 complex analysis

Comment: What? Which book? Or question? How to download? Where? @What'sup

Comment: finally possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2?lq=1
just write in google

Comment: Woooww thank you so much:)))) @what'sup Is not there any difference btw these two questions? There are the same, not similar. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we'll use the integral $$ \oint_{C_N} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } \ dz $$

where $C_N $ is the square contour of side $ 2N + 1 $

By residues theory :

$$  \oint_{C_N} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } \ dz = 2\pi i\left( \sum_{-N}^N \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , n \right) + \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , bi \right) + \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , -bi \right) \right)$$

the integral $ \to 0 $ as $ N \to \infty $

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{-\infty }^{\infty} \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , n \right) + \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , bi \right) + \mathrm{Res} \left( \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + b^2 } , -bi \right) = 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2}  + \sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2 } + \frac{1}{b^2} +   \lim_{z \to bi} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z + bi} + \lim_{z \to -bi} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z - bi} = 0$$

$$ \Rightarrow 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2 } + \frac{1}{b^2} - \frac{\pi\coth(b\pi)}{b} = 0 $$

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2 } =  \frac{\pi\coth(b\pi)}{2b} - \frac{1}{2b^2}  $$

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is so clear:)

Comment: glad it helped :-)