# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^2}{1+n^2z^2}$ converges to analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

> For which $z$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^2}{1+n^2z^2}$ converge to an analytic function? What are its poles?

I think the poles should be $\pm\dfrac{i}{n}$, since those are the values at which one of the denominators disappear. I'm not sure about the converging to analytic function part

Comment: It might be easier to write $z = 1/w$ and consider the sum as a function of $w$.

Comment: This should be $\frac{iz}{2}\left( \pi\cot (i\pi/z)+iz\right)$.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141470/38053). Or better, [that thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2?lq=1).

Comment: @julien you beat me to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum have closed form. As [it was proved earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179/19538)
$$
f(w)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-w^2}=\frac{1}{2w}\left(\frac{1}{w}-\pi\cot(\pi z)\right)
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^2}{1+n^2z^2}=f(i/z)=-\frac{1}{2} z \left(z-\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{z}\right)\right)
$$
So the question simplifies significantly

Comment: (+1) I don't see right away why this is true.  Could you give me a link or some explanation?

Comment: soon I'll post an explanation