# How to sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone know the general strategy for summing a series of the form:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2},$$

where $a$ is a positive integer?

Any hints or ideas would be great!

Comment: The following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/) may prove useful reading.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certain series of the form $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty f(n)$ can be evaluated by means of residue calculus. One important result which is useful to this problem states that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C \setminus \{z_1,\ldots, z_k\}$ (where the $z_i$ are the isolated singularities of $f$) and $|zf(z)|$ is bounded for $|z|$ sufficiently large, then $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty f(n)$ is the negative of the sum of the residues of $\pi \cot(\pi z)f(z)$ at the $z_i$, provided none of the $z_i$ are integers. You can find more information in Marsden's *Basic Complex Analysis* text.

To apply the result to this problem, first note that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} - \frac{1}{2a^2}$$ Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 + a^2}$. Then $f$ has simple poles at $z = ai$ and $z = -ai$. For $|z| \ge \max\{1, 2a\}$, $$|zf(z)| \le \frac{|z|}{|z|^2 - a^2} \le \dfrac{|z|}{|z|^2 - \frac{|z|^2}{4}} = \frac{4}{3|z|} \le \frac{4}{3}$$

Therefore

\begin{align}-\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} &= \text{Res}_{z = ai} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + a^2} + \text{Res}_{z = -ai} \frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)}{z^2 + a^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi\cot(\pi ai)}{2ai} - \frac{\pi\cot(-\pi ai)}{2ai}\\
&= -\frac{\pi\coth(\pi a)}{2a} - \frac{\pi \coth(\pi a)}{2a}\\
&= -\frac{\pi\coth(\pi a)}{a}\end{align}

Hence,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} = \frac{\pi\coth(\pi a)}{2a} - \frac{1}{2a^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly enlightened, but you can look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2F%28n%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29+from+n%3D1+to+n%3Dinfinity) to see the answer, which may help with the explanation.

Comment: I understand that, nur can you explain why the contour integral tends to $0$ which allows you to do These calculations. It must have to do With the boundness For large $\vert z \vert$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fractional expansion of $\cot z$, you can get:

$$\frac{1}{e^t-1} -\frac{1}{t} +\frac{1}{2} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2t}{t^2 +4n^2\pi^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), then use the [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) between trigonometric and hyperbolic functions.