# Evaluate the sum $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2+a^4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Evaluate the sum $\sum ^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2+a^4}$

I don't to know how to processed this problem. Can any one help with problem please. thanks

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi  a^2 \coth \left(\pi  a^2\right)+1}{2 a^4}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner..how it comes

Comment: Complex analysis is acceptable?

Comment: Have a look at 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064217/how-to-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-a2
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314986/value-of-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2a2
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D_%7Bn%3D1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%2Ba%5E4%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, **Approach0** looks awesome. Thank you for letting me know such a nice search engine!

Comment: @SangchulLee You can find links to some further information [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148/2016/10/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex analysis gives a very clear explanation of the identity

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+z^2} = \frac{1}{z}\bigg( \frac{\pi}{2}\coth(\pi z) - \frac{1}{2z} \bigg) $$

where $z = a^2$. This equality follows from the observation that both sides have exactly the same poles and decay to $0$ as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$.

---

If you want to avoid complex-analysis method, there are some alternatives. Let me briefly discuss the idea. Let $b = a^2$ and assume that $b > 0$. Using the following Fourier transform,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(nx) e^{-b|x|} \, dx = \frac{2b}{n^2 + b^2}, $$

we can perform the following heuristic computation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2}
= \frac{1}{2b} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(nx)e^{-b|x|} \, dx
\color{red}{\stackrel{!?}{=}} \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(nx) \bigg) e^{-b|x|} \, dx. $$

Now using the (distributional) Poisson summation formula

$$ 2\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x - 2\pi n)
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{inx}
= 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(nx), $$

we find that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2}
&\color{red}{\stackrel{!?}{=}} \frac{1}{2b} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( \pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x - 2\pi n) - \frac{1}{2} \bigg) e^{-b|x|} \, dx \\
&\color{red}{\stackrel{!?}{=}} \frac{1}{2b} \bigg( \pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi b |n|} - \frac{1}{b} \bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{2b}\bigg( \pi\coth(\pi b) - \frac{1}{b} \bigg).
\end{align*}

Up to this point, all the computations are only heuristic and desperately require some rigorous justification. Fortunately not much extra work is required. All this nonsense can be salvaged by adopting an appropriate regularization.

Indeed, using the dominated convergence theorem, we may safely write

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2}
&= \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n^2 + b^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2b} \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(nx)e^{-b|x|} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2b} \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n \cos(nx) \bigg) e^{-b|x|} \, dx
\end{align*}

Then from the formula of the 2-dimensional Poisson kernel

$$ \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos x + r^2} = 1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n \cos(nx), \qquad |r| < 1$$

we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + b^2}
&= \frac{1}{2b} \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos x + r^2} - \frac{1}{2} \bigg) e^{-b|x|} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2b} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r\cos x + r^2} \bigg( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-b|x+2\pi n|} \bigg) \, dx - \frac{1}{b} \bigg).
\end{align*}

Notice that $x \mapsto \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-b|x+2\pi n|}$ defines a continuous function. Thus by appealing to the *approximation-to-the-identity* property of the Poisson kernel, we obtain the same answer as in the heuristics.

Comment: great solutions

Comment: i really thanks to all mathsstack users ..i learned many things form here

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Sangchul's answer above is great and satisfying, but From [here](http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/series-calculator/?f=1%2F%28n%5E%282%29%2Bk%29&var=n&a=1&b=inf), we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k + n^{2}}=- \frac{\sqrt{- k}}{2 k} (- \psi{ (0,- \sqrt{- k} + 1  )} + \psi{ (0,\sqrt{- k} + 1  )})=- \frac{0.5}{k}(- k)^{0.5} (-\psi{(0,- \sqrt{- k} + 1 )} + \psi{(0,\sqrt{- k} + 1 )})$$ where $\psi$ is the [Polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) Function implemented in the Mathematica way;this may be of some help.