# Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^k}\zeta(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form, riemann-zeta

We can prove that 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\zeta(n)=\gamma$$

In fact, If we let $f(z)=\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}m z^m$, then by the method which used in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505573/infinite-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac-zetankn?rq=1),

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\zeta(n)=\sum_{n=1}^nf\left(\frac1 n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{mn^m}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1 n+\log\left(1-\frac1 n\right)\right)=\gamma$$

Is there any known value for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^k}\zeta(n)$ for every natural number $k\ge2$? What is the best result?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311735/a-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-1n-ln-left1-frac12n-right/2312239?noredirect=1#comment4760984_2312239

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this can help, probably not, but from $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}}{n}\zeta\left(n\right)=x\gamma+\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)$$ we can get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n-1}}{n}\zeta\left(n\right)=\gamma+\frac{\log\left(\Gamma\left(x+1\right)\right)}{x}$$ and so $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}}{n^{2}}\zeta\left(n\right)=\gamma x+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\log\left(\Gamma\left(y+1\right)\right)}{y}dy$$ note that for $x=1$ we have the GEdgar's result. With the same method, we can get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n}}{n^{3}}\zeta\left(n\right)=\gamma x+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\log\left(\Gamma\left(y+1\right)\right)}{y}dy\right)dt$$ and so on. Surely these integrals are quite frightful.

Comment: It seems that there is no a nice closed form yet!

Answer (score 8):

I only get
$$
\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}\zeta  \left( n
 \right) }{{n}^{2}}}
=
\gamma+\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {\ln  \left( \Gamma  \left( s+1 \right) 
 \right) }{s}}{ds}
$$
Probably not much help.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @draks... take the logarithm of Weierstrass' form of the Gamma function  to obtain $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\zeta(n)}{n}x^n=\gamma x+\log\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: @nospoon is there a square missing ?

Comment: @draks... No. divide the above equation by $x$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$.