# Logarithmic series as $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311735/a-closed-form-of-sum-n-1-infty-1n-ln-left1-frac12n-right), I've designed the following series.

> $$
> \begin{align}
> S&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right) \tag1
> \\\\
> T&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right) \tag2
> \end{align}
> $$

Each one admits a *nice* closed form.

*Q1. What are their closed forms?*

*Q2. To which family would you tell these series belong to ?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Answering Q1.*

One has

> $$
> \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)=\ln\!\Big(\frac32\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac76\Big)+\ln\!\Big(\frac54\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac98\Big). \tag1
> $$

*Proof*. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \left[\frac{(2n-3)(n+2)}{(2n+5)(n-2)}\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left[\frac{(2n-3)(2n+4)}{(2n+5)(2n-4)}\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\left[\ln \!\left(\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{2n+5}{2n+4}\right)\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\left[\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n-2)}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n-2)}\right)-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)
\\=&\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2(n+2)}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\sum_{\color{blue}{n=3}}^{\infty}\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)
\\=&\ln\!\Big(\frac32\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac76\Big)+\ln\!\Big(\frac54\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac98\Big),
\end{align}
$$ where we have made a change of index.

Similarly, one has

> $$
> \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)=\ln\!\Big(\frac54\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac98\Big)-\ln\!\Big(\frac32\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac76\Big). \tag2
> $$

*Proof*. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \left[\frac{(2n-3)(n+2)}{(2n+5)(n-2)}\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left[\frac{(2n-3)(2n+4)}{(2n+5)(2n-4)}\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\left[\ln \!\left(\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{2n+5}{2n+4}\right)\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\left[\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n-2)}\right)-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)\right]
\\=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big) \!\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n-2)}\right)-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\Big(1+\frac1{2n}\Big)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)
\\=&\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+\color{red}{2}}\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2(n+2)}\right) \!\ln \!\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-\sum_{\color{blue}{n=3}}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}\right)
\\=&-\ln\!\Big(\frac32\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac76\Big)+\ln\!\Big(\frac54\Big) \!\ln \!\Big(\frac98\Big),
\end{align}
$$ where we have made a change of index.

*Answering Q2.*

The given series are just an instance  ($k=1$) of the following family.

> **Proposition.** Let $k=1,2,3,\cdots.$ Then
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> {\small \sum_{n=2k+1}^{\infty}}&{\small \ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n}\!\right) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-8k^2+2k}{2n^2+n-8k^2-2k}\!\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{2k}\ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n}\!\right) \!\ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n+4k}\!\right)}, \tag3
> \\\\
> {\small \sum_{n=2k+1}^{\infty}(-1)^n} &{\small \ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n}\!\right) \!\ln \!\left(\!\frac{2n^2+n-8k^2+2k}{2n^2+n-8k^2-2k}\!\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{2k}(-1)^n\ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n}\!\right) \!\ln\!\left(\!1+\frac1{2n+4k}\!\right)}. \tag4
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: Very nicely done

Answer (score 7):

Noting that
$$ 2n^2+n-6=(n+2)(2n-3),2n^2+n-10=(n-2)(2n+5)$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{2n^2+n-6}{2n^2+n-10}\!\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{(n+2)(2n-3)}{(n-2)(2n+5)}\!\right)\\
&=&-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right) \!\ln \!\left(\frac{(2n+5)(2n-4)}{(2n-3)(2n+4)}\!\right)\\
&=&-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\ln\!\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right) \!\left(\ln\frac{2n+5}{2n+4}-\ln\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\right)\\
&=&-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right) \!\left(\ln\left(\frac{2n+5}{2n+4}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\right)\right)\right]\\
&=&-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\left[\ln\left(\frac{2n+5}{2n+4}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right) -\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n}\right)ln\left(\frac{2n-3}{2n-4}\right)\right]\\
&=&-\bigg[\ln\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)\ln\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)\ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\\
&&+\ln\left(\frac{15}{14}\right)\ln\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)\ln\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{19}{18}\right)\ln\left(\frac{15}{14}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{15}{14}\right)\ln\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)\\
&&+\ln\left(\frac{23}{22}\right)\ln\left(\frac{19}{18}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{19}{18}\right)\ln\left(\frac{15}{14}\right)+\cdots\bigg]\\
&=&\ln\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\ln\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)\ln\left(\frac{5}{4}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
One can use the same way to handle $T$.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: Impressive @xpaul