# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{x(e^{x}-1)(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> \begin{equation}
> \int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{x(e^{x}-1)(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx
> \end{equation}

My colleague got this problem from his friend but he didn't know the answer so he asked my help. Unfortunately, after hours of tired effort I was unable to crack this integral. I was unable to find a way to evaluate it from online search either. I used to be good at solving this kind of problem but now I feel so embarrassed by my stupidity. I'm stuck and I badly need your help. It's a humbling request to ask people here being so kind to help me out. Thank you.

Comment: That is a lot of text not having with the problem to do. Please tell us instead what you have tried.

Comment: @mickep Thank for your comment but what kind of useless effort did you expect me to put in my answer? Even if I put it there, I'm afraid it's still of no use.

Comment: Well, you could for one thing mention that you are looking for answers in terms of elementary functions only, or perhaps with Beta and Polygamma functions. THAT would have been useful information.

Comment: I'm quite sure the use of the Hurwitz zeta function can be avoided after using substitution $y=e^{-x}$ and applying the Feynman's method as shown in @OlivierOloa's answer

Comment: @zyx Of course you may, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 37):

**Hint**. An approach. One may consider
$$
I(s):=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{(e^{x}-1)(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx,\quad s>0, \tag1
$$ which one may rewrite as $I_1(s)+I_2(s)$ with

$$
\begin{align}
I_1(s):=&\frac12\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{(e^{x}-1)}dx\\\\ I_2(s):=&-\frac12\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{\left(1-e^{-x}(1+x )\right)(1-e^{-x})}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx
\end{align}
$$ each of the preceding integrals is a linear combination of the standard evaluations
$$
\begin{align}
a(s,r)=&\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{e^{-rx}}{(e^{x}-1)}dx=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s,r+1)
\\\\ b(s,r)=&\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\frac{e^{-rx}}{(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx=\Gamma(s) \left(4^{-s}\zeta\left(s,\frac{1+r}{4}\right)-4^{-s}\zeta\left(s,\frac{3+r}{4}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$ where $\zeta(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

Finally one gets that $2I(s)$ is equal to
$$
a(s,0)-a(s,1)-a(s+1,1)-b(s,0)+2b(s,1)+b(s+1,1)-b(s,2)-b(s+1,2)
$$ which as $s \to 0^+$ gives $I(0)=I$:

> $$
> I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{x(e^{x}-1)(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx=\frac{\pi}8-\frac{\gamma}2+\frac12\ln \pi-\frac34\ln 2
> $$

confirming @Claude Leibovici's announced result, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Ah. I find you're really a *master* of this "Hurwitz zeta function", after reviewing some of your past posts :)

Comment: I'm unhappy with the use of a special function like Hurwitz zeta function to evaluate this integral, but the answer is gratefully received nonetheless. Upvoted.

Comment: @Sophie, since $\gamma$ is involved in the final result, a path that avoids special functions seems unlikely. Olivier, nice use of Mellin!

Comment: This is a beautiful and elegant solution, indeed. Thanks for providing it !

Comment: @J.M. You seem to misunderstand my comment. I didn't object to the use of all special functions. I feel the Hurwitz zeta function or the Lerch zeta function is less familiar with the other special functions like the beta function or the polygamma function. I still appreciate this answer, though.

Comment: @SophieAgnesi : when expanding as Taylor series in $\exp$ the quotient of $\exp$, you'll get the Hurwitz zeta at $s=2$ and $a=1/4,1/2$, or the Dirichlet beta at $s= 2$ : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}(2n+1)^{-2}$  and $\zeta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$

Comment: note that you can prove the values of those series with the residue theorem (proving implicitely the functional equation for $\zeta$ functions) , and Taylor expanding (in $x$ this time) $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ and $\frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}$ (no need for the full Taylor series, only the first 2 coefs). so what I mean is that there is no elementary answer  anyway

Comment: @SophieAgnesi Do note that you can click the checkmark button to mark this answer as "accepted".  It's right below the up/down voting.

Comment: @SimpleArt Why would I do that if this answer doesn't satisfy me?? Don't get me wrong Olivier, I do appreciate your answer.

Comment: @SophieAgnesi : see what I wrote, you have to be satisfied of this answer, because there is no much simpler way

Comment: @SophieAgnesi Ok, as you wish.  I just personally am very satisfied with this answer.  :)

Answer (score 12):

*This is **not** an answer but **just** a result.*

Being unable to crack this integral, I made a numerical evaluation and I gave the result to the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc). The result is apparently $$\frac{1}{8} \left(\pi +\log \left(\frac{\pi ^4}{64} \right)-4 \gamma\right)$$ ($\gamma$ being Euler's constant).

This is correct at least for $500$ significant figures.

Now, I am curious to see how the problem could be tackled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Claude. I really appreciate it but I cannot upvote your answer for the time being.

Comment: @SophieAgnesi. As I wrote, this is **not** an answer but just a result ! Cheers.

Comment: Is gamma the Euler constant?

Comment: @Vim. Yes, it is. I shall add this in my "answer".

Comment: Wow, 7 upvotes for a result which is not answer! I've got to try that myself, too!

Comment: @AlexM. To my surprise, be sure ! As I said, I did not do anything. Cheers ... and try !

Comment: @AlexM. We just like that it came out somewhat simply, but it seems so hard to actually get that answer.  When math comes out this 'beautifully', one can't help but to upvote.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I can understand that, but it is entirely the merit of the programmers of the inverse symbolic calculator. (Note: the downvote isn't mine.)

Comment: @AlexM. :-) ${}$

Answer (score 11):

**Here is an elementary way:**

Denote the wanted integral by $I$. First we note that we can write your integrand as
$$
\frac{2+x+xe^x}{2x(1+e^{2x})}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{e^x-1}.
$$
Now, we have two diverging parts, but [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals)
$$
\gamma=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{xe^x}\,dx,
$$
we add and subtract with $1/(2xe^x)$. We get
$$
I=-\frac{\gamma}{2}+\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x(e^{-x}+e^{-2x})-(e^{-x}-e^{-2x})+(e^{-2x}-e^{-3x})}{2x(1+e^{-2x})}\,dx.
$$
With
$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^ke^{-2kx},
$$
we find that $I+\gamma/2$ equals (no problem with convergence, so we can change order of integration and summation)
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\int_0^{+\infty}
e^{-(1+2k)x}+e^{-(2+2k)x}-\frac{e^{-(1+2k)x}-e^{-(2+2k)x}}{x}+\frac{e^{-(2+2k)x}-e^{-(3+2k)x}}{x}\,dx.
$$
All integrals are easily calculated (exponentials and Frullani), and we find that $I+\gamma/2$ equals
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\Bigl[\frac{1}{1+2k}+\frac{1}{2+2k}-\log\frac{2+2k}{1+2k}+\log\frac{3+2k}{2+2k}\Bigr]
$$
The first two parts should be known from Maclaurin series of $\arctan x$ and $\log(1+x)$. The second two terms are combined and calculated using the [Wallis product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)). The result of the series is
$$
\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\log 2+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
Thus, we have found that
$$
I=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x)}{x(e^x-1)(e^x+e^{-x})}\,dx=-\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\log 2+\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$

Comment: Only the integral for $\gamma$ is nonelementary here; well-done, you!

Answer (score 10):

I answer my own OP instead of improving it as a proof to user [@mickep](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816901/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac1-e-x1x-xex-1exe-xdx#comment3712590_1816901) that I did give a try to this problem but I didn't want to post some useless efforts like "I ***tried*** substitution $x=\tan y$ then I failed... *miserably*". I consider putting this kind of effort is a a complete joke as shown in some posts with [integration](/questions/tagged/integration) tag.

Okay, here is my try. Following user [@Anastasiya-Romanova秀](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816901/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac1-e-x1x-xex-1exe-xdx#comment3712800_1816901)'s suggestion, I use the substitution $y=e^{-x}$ and the original integral becomes

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\frac{y(y-1)-y^2\log y}{(1-y)(1+y^2)\log y}dy=-\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\left(\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{1}{\log y}\right)dy
\end{equation}

Now, we consider the following parametric integral

\begin{equation}
I(a):=\int_0^1\frac{y^{a-1}}{1+y^2}\left(\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{1}{\log y}\right)dy
\end{equation}

Differentiating $I(a)$ we get

\begin{align}
I'(a)& =\int_0^1\left(\frac{\log y}{1-y}+1\right)\frac{y^{a-1}}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{y^{a}\log y}{1-y^4}dy+\int_0^1\frac{y^{a+1}\log y}{1-y^4}dy+\int_0^1\frac{y^{a-1}}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\left(y^{4k+a}\log y+y^{4k+a+1}\log y+(-1)^ky^{2k+a-1}\right)dy\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{(4k+a+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(4k+a+2)^2}+\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+a}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left(-\psi_1\!\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)-\psi_1\!\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right)+4\psi\!\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right)-4\psi\!\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)\right)
\end{align}

where I use [the following relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Series_representation)

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k)^{m+1}}=\frac1{(-2)^{m+1}m!}\!\left(\psi_m\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)-\psi_m\!\left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

Hence

\begin{equation}
I(a)=\int_{\infty}^aI'(a)\ da=-\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(\frac{a+1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right)+\log\Gamma\!\left(\frac{a+2}{4}\right)-\log\Gamma\!\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)
\end{equation}

Hence our considered problem is $\color{red}{-I(2)}$ which confirms user [@ClaudeLeibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1816918/346183)'s  result.

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x )}{x(e^{x}-1)(e^{x}+e^{-x})}dx&=\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\psi\!\left(1\right)+\log\Gamma\!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\[10pt]
&=\frac{1}{8}\left(\pi+\log\left(\frac{\pi ^4}{64}\right)-4\gamma\right)
\end{align}

where I use [special value of the digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values)

\begin{equation}
\psi\!\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}-3\log2-\gamma
\end{equation}

and [the reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)

\begin{equation}
\psi\!\left(1-x\right)-\psi\!\left(x\right)=\pi\cot\pi x
\end{equation}

***Done!***

Comment: nicely done! Where'd you to integrate like this?

Answer (score 9):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-x}(1+x)}{x(e^x-1)(e^x+e^{-x})}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x-(1+x)}{x(e^x-1)(e^{2x}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}\frac1{(e^x-1)(e^{2x}+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}\,\frac12\left(\frac1{e^x-1}-\frac{1+e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(e^{(1-4j)x}+e^{-4jx}\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{k(4j-1)^k}+\frac1{k(4j)^k}\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(\frac{4j-1}{4j-2}\right)-\frac1{4j-1}\right]\\
&+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(\frac{4j}{4j-1}\right)-\frac1{4j}\right]\tag{6}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(\frac{j}{j-\frac12}\right)-\frac1{2j}+\frac14\left(\frac1j-\frac1{j-\frac14}\right)\right]\tag{7}\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\right)-\frac\gamma2+\frac14H_{-1/4}\tag{8}\\[9pt]
&=\frac12\log(\pi)-\frac\gamma2+\frac\pi8-\frac34\log(2)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: multiply numerator and denominator by $e^x$
$(2)$: expand $e^x-(1+x)$ into a power series
$(3)$: partial fractions
$(4)$: expand into a power series
$(5)$: perform the integration using the Gamma integral
$(6)$: use the power series for $\log(1+x)$
$(7)$: arithmetic
$(8)$: $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+x)=\frac{\Gamma(n+x)}{\Gamma(1+x)}$, [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028), $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)=\gamma$,
$\phantom{(8)\text{:}}$ and $(2)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506068)
$(9)$: $(11)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506068)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is pretty neat. (+1)

Comment: I really should post that transcript of Gautschi's paper, it's been years... :D

Comment: @J.M.: That would be nice. I've been citing my answer; it would be nice to cite something in print.