# Showing $\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n}-x\over 1+x}\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}=\ln\left({2\over \pi}\cdot{(2n)!!\over (2n-1)!!}\right)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, infinite-product

Integrate

> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n}-x\over 1+x}\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}=\ln\left({2\over \pi}\cdot{(2n)!!\over (2n-1)!!}\right)\tag1$$

$${x^{2n}-x\over 1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(x^{2n}-x)x^k\tag2$$

Sub $(2)$ into $(1)\rightarrow (3)$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}(x^{2n+k}-x^{k+1})\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}\tag3$$
Frullani's theorem

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x^m-x^n)\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}=\ln{m+1 \over n+1}\tag4$$

Apply $(4)$ to $(3)\rightarrow (5)$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ln\left({2n+k+1\over k+2}\right)\tag5$$

$${2\over \pi}={(2n-1)!!\over (2n)!}\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\left({2n+k+1\over k+2}\right)^{(-1)^k}\tag6$$

Comment: Abstract duplicate of a question you already asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818436/prove-int-0-infty1-over-x-cdot1-e-phix-over-1e-phixdx-ln

Comment: What is abstract duplicate? Have I already asked this question? Why are you the only person marking down my question with so called duplicate? When I see more than a finger I start to believe in you.

Comment: Abstract duplicate because it is not an exact duplicate, but the techniques shown in the answers to your previous question clearly solve this problem, too, so this actual question is redundant, in my opinion. In any case, I am just A finger, not many fingers.

Comment: It is easy to say when you have knowledge in maths. How is the other question be also duplicate?

Comment: For instance: take the product in $(6)$ for $0\leq k\leq 2N$. Split the even $k$s and the odd ones, collect pieces, simplify, take the limit as $N\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enforce the substitution $x\to e^{-x}$ to write

$$\begin{align}
I(n)&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}-x}{1+x}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2nx}}{x}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(k+2)x}-e^{-(k+2n+1)x}}{x}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \log\left(\frac{k+2n+1}{k+2}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \log\left(\frac{k+2n}{k+1}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, note that we can write the partial sum

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2N} (-1)^{k-1} \log\left(\frac{k+2n}{k+1}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^N  \log\left(\frac{2k-1+2n}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^N \log\left(\frac{2k+2n}{2k+1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N  \log\left(\frac{2k-1+2n}{2k+2n}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^N \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+N}  \log\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^N \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+N}  \log\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n+N} \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&-\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \log\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=N+1}^{n+N} \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+N}  \log\left(\frac{(2k-1)(2k+1)}{(2k)(2k)}\right)\\\\
&+\log\left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)-\sum_{k=N+1}^{n+N} \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Recalling [Wallis' Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), we see that

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n+N}  \log\left(\frac{(2k-1)(2k+1)}{(2k)(2k)}\right)=-\log(\pi/2)$$

And since $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n+N} \log\left(\frac{2k+1}{2k}\right)=0$, we find

$$I(n)=\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right)$$

as was to be shown!!

---

**APPENDIX:**

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079609/prove-that-int-01xx2-cdotsx2n-2nx-over-1x-lnxdx-ln-left/2079834#2079834), I evaluated the integral

$$J(n)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}-x}{1+x}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx=\log\left(\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)$$

by making use of the integral evaluated herein.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} - x \over 1 + x}\,{\dd x\over \ln\pars{x}}} =
-\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} - x \over 1 + x}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{y}\,\dd y}^{\ds{-\,{1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}}\
\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n + y} - x^{1 + y} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y + 2n} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y + 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}\,\dd y\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

However, by using the [well known digamma $\Psi$ function identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E16)
$\ds{\left.\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{z - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t
\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{z}\ >\ 0} = \Psi\pars{z} + \gamma\quad}$
where $\gamma$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*:
\begin{align}
\fbox{$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}$} &=
2\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{-1/2} - x^{z/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{-1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{z} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & = \fbox{$\ds{%
\Psi\pars{{z \over 2} + \half} - \Psi\pars{\half} - \Psi\pars{z + 1} - \gamma}$}
\end{align}

we get, after replacing in $\pars{1}$,
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} - x \over 1 + x}\,{\dd x\over \ln\pars{x}}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{y \over 2} + n + \half} -
\Psi\pars{y + 2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{{y \over 2} + 1} + \Psi\pars{y + 2}}\,\dd y
\end{align}

Since
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z}\ \stackrel{\mbox{def.}}{=}\
     \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2n} - x \over 1 + x}\,{\dd x\over \ln\pars{x}}} =
\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma^{2}\pars{y/2 + n + 1/2}\Gamma\pars{y + 2} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{y/2 + 1}\Gamma\pars{y + 2n + 1}}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \infty}
\\[3mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{%
\ln\pars{2^{1 - 2n}\,{\Gamma\pars{2n + 1} \over \Gamma^{2}\pars{n + 1/2}}}}
\end{align}

Could you simplify it ?.