# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x)(x-3)\over 1+x^2}\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}={\ln{8\over \Gamma^4(3/4)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Prove

> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x)(x-3)\over 1+x^2}\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}=\color{blue}{\ln{8\over \Gamma^4(3/4)}}\tag1$$

$(1-x)(x-3)=-x^2+4x-3$

$${1\over 1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}\tag2$$

$$I=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2n+2}-4x^{2n+1}+3x^{2n}\over \ln{x}}dx\tag3$$

Rewrite (3) to apply Frullani's theorem

$$I=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2n+2}-x^{2n+1}-3x^{2n+1}+3x^{2n}\over \ln{x}}dx\tag4$$

$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\ln\left({2n+3\over (2n+2)^4}\cdot{(2n+1)^3}\right)\tag5$$

This method is a bit boring method! I converted (1) into series and using Frullani's theorem and again have to solve the series is another step before we can reached our answer.

How can I solve (1) without using series?

Comment: I think you cannot. Here $\Gamma(3/4)$ comes from an infinite product, hence $\log\Gamma(3/4)$ is a series of logarithms related to $(5)$.

Comment: And anyhow, this question is almost the same as your previous http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821080/showing-int-01x2n-x-over-1x-cdotdx-over-lnx-ln-left2-over

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The question really is not the same inasmuch as the integrand is substantively different from the previous one.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV: the meaning of the previous "*almost the same*" is *"a question that can be solved like the other one, with really minor changes*". Abstract duplicate, for short.

Comment: you should write your complete list of formulas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**. One may set
$$
f(s):=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4s}-1}{(1+x^2)\ln x}dx, \quad s>0. \tag1
$$ In order to get rid of the factor $\ln x$ in the denominator, we may differentiate under the integral sign getting
$$
f'(s)=4\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4s}}{1+x^2}dx=4\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4s}(1-x^2)}{1-x^4}dx, \quad s>0, \tag2
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
f'(s)&=\psi\left(s+\frac34\right)-\psi\left(s+\frac14\right),\tag3
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the standard [integral representation of the digamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E16)
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{s - 1} \over 1 - t}\,dt
\, = \psi (s)+ \gamma, \quad s>0,
$$ $\gamma$ being the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Then integrating $(3)$, observing that as $s \to 0^+$, $f(s) \to 0$, one gets

> $$
> f(s)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{4s}-1}{(1+x^2)\ln x}dx=\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(s+\frac34\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)\Gamma\left(s+\frac14\right)}\right), \quad s>0, \tag4
> $$

from which you deduce the value of your initial integral by writing 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{(1-x)(x-3)\over 1+x^2}\cdot{dx\over \ln{x}}=f(1/2)+4f(1/4).
$$

Comment: How do you cancel the logarithm after differentiating f(s)?

Comment: Thank you @Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks

Comment: Very well done!  +1 -Mark

Comment: @China cat You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}\pars{x - 3} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{3 - x \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\
\overbrace{{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}^{\ds{4\int_{0}^{1/4}x^{4y}\,\dd y}}\
\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
4\int_{0}^{1/4}\int_{0}^{1}{3x^{4y} - x^{4y + 1} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
4\int_{0}^{1/4}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{3x^{4y} - x^{4y + 1}}\pars{1 - x^{2}} \over 1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm] & =
4\int_{0}^{1/4}\int_{0}^{1}
{3x^{4y} - 3x^{4y + 2} - x^{4y + 1} + x^{4y + 3}\over 1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm] & \stackrel{x^{4}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\
\int_{0}^{1/4}\int_{0}^{1}
{3x^{y - 3/4} - 3x^{y - 1/4} - x^{y - 1/2} + x^{y}\over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[8mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1/4}\left(%
3\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y - 1/4}\over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y - 1/2}\over 1 - x}\,\dd x\right.
\\[3mm] & \left.\phantom{\int_{0}^{1/4}\pars{}}-
3\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y - 3/4}\over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{y}\over 1 - x}\,\dd x\right)\,\dd y
\\[8mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1/4}\bracks{3\,\Psi\pars{y + {3 \over 4}} +
\Psi\pars{y + \half} - 3\,\Psi\pars{y + {1 \over 4}} -\Psi\pars{y + 1}}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] & =
\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{y + 3/4}\Gamma\pars{y + 1/2} \over \Gamma^{\,3}\pars{y + 1/4}\Gamma\pars{y + 1}}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1/4} =
\ln\pars{{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1}\Gamma\pars{3/4} \over \Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1/2}\Gamma\pars{5/4}}
{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1} \over \Gamma^{\,3}\pars{3/4}\Gamma\pars{1/2}}}
\\[3mm] & =
\ln\pars{{1 \over \Gamma^{\,4}\pars{1/2}}\
{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma\pars{5/4}\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{3/4}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{1 \over \Gamma^{\,4}\pars{1/2}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1 \over \pi^{2}}\quad
\mbox{because}\quad \ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}
\\[5mm]
\ds{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma\pars{5/4}\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{3/4}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{{\Gamma^{\,3}\pars{1/4} \over \pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/4}\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{3/4}} =
4\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/4} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}^{2}}
\\[1mm] & \ds{=} &
\ds{4\bracks{{1 \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}\,{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}\sin\pars{\pi/4}}}^{2} =
{8\pi^{2} \over \Gamma^{\,4}\pars{3/4}}}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

With $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$:
$$
\color{#f00}{I} \equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}\pars{x - 3} \over 1 + x^{2}}
\,{\dd x \over \ln\pars{x}} =
\color{#f00}{\ln\pars{8 \over \Gamma^{\,4}\pars{3/4}}}
$$