# How to solve the limit of this sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{3\cdot 8}+\dots+\frac{1}{6(2n-1)(3n+1)} \right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{3\cdot 8}+\dots+\frac{1}{6(2n-1)(3n+1)} \right)$$
I have tried to split the subset into telescopic series but got no result.
I also have tried to use the squeeze theorem by putting the $a_n$ between $\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$ and $\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}$ but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{6(2n-1)(3n+1)}=\frac{1}{(6n-3)(6n+2)}=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1}{6n-3}-\frac{1}{6n+2}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1\left(x^{6n-4}-x^{6n+1}\right)$$

by using partial fractions and noting that $\int_0^1x^a\,dx=\frac{1}{a+1}$. Then:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{6(2n-1)(3n+1)}=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^N\left(x^{6n-4}-x^{6n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1(x^2-x^7)\frac{1-x^{6N}}{1-x^6}\,dx$$

and this last integral is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1(x^2-x^7)\frac{1}{1-x^6}\,dx-\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1\frac{x^{6N+2}(1-x^5)}{1-x^6}\,dx$$

Upon cancelling fractions, the first of these is equal to $\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1x^2\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5}\,dx$, and the latter can be shown to be convergent to $0$ by noting that $\frac{1-x^5}{1-x^6}\le1$ on the given interval and $\int_0^1x^{6N+2}\,dx\to0$.

So, the series converges to $\frac{1}{5}\int_0^1x^2\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4}{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5}\,dx$.

This integral can be evaluated exactly, if needed, by expanding the integrand into partial fractions.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively one may recall the [series representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6) for the digamma function
$$\begin{equation} 
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n+x} -\frac{1}{n}  
\right), \quad \Re x >-1, \tag1
\end{equation}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Then by partial fraction decomposition we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(6n-3)(6n+2)} &= \frac15\left(\frac{1}{6n-3}-\frac{1}{6n+2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{30}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n-1/2}-\frac1n\right)-\left(\frac{1}{n+1/3}-\frac1n\right)\right]
\end{align}
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $+\infty$, using $(1)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(6n-3)(6n+2)} =\frac1{30}\left(\psi\left(\frac43\right)-\psi\left(\frac12\right)\right)
$$ equivalently

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(6n-3)(6n+2)} =\frac{1}{180} \left(18-\sqrt{3} \pi -9 \ln 3+24 \ln 2\right)
> $$

where we have used [special values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) of the digamma function.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506068), we see that
$$
H_{-1/2}=-2\log(2)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
H_{-2/3}=-\frac32\log(3)-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
H_{1/3}=3-\frac32\log(3)-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}\tag{3}
$$
Applying $(1)$ and $(3)$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{6(2k-1)(3k+1)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{30}\left(\frac2{2k-1}-\frac3{3k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac1{30}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+\frac13}\right)
-\frac1{30}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k-\frac12}\right)\\
&=\frac1{30}\left(H_{1/3}-H_{-1/2}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{30}\left(3-\frac32\log(3)-\frac\pi{2\sqrt3}+2\log(2)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{18-9\log(3)-\pi\sqrt3+12\log(2)}{180}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Actually, $H_{x}$ is equal to $\gamma+\psi(x+1)$, right?

Comment: Yes. I used $H_x$ since that is what is used in the cited post.