# Is there a closed form for this integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x-1\over e^{ax}-1} dx?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

Does this integral $(1)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x-1\over e^{ax}-1} dx=F(a)\tag1$$

$a\ge1$

has a closed form?

We may rewrite it as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{1\over e^{x(a-1)}-e^{-x}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}{1\over e^{ax}-1} dx=F(a)\tag2$$

we have $$\zeta(s)={1\over \Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s-1}\over e^{x}-1}dx\tag3$$

---

Guess of a closed form for $F(a)$

$$F(a)=\color{red}{{\pi\over 2a}\cot\left({\pi\over a}\right)}-{1\over a}\ln(2a)+
{2\over a}\sum_{n=1}^{\left\lfloor {a-1\over 2}\right\rfloor}\cos\left({2n\pi\over a}\right)\ln\sin\left({n\pi\over a}\right)\tag4$$

I was checking on the wolfram integral, the red part give part of the closed form but the black part seem to be a mistake somewhere I can't figured it out.

According to wolfram integral:

$$F(2)=\ln(2)$$

$$F(3)={1\over 2}\ln(3)-{\sqrt{3}\over 18}\pi$$

$$F(4)={3\over 4}\ln(2)-{\pi\over 8}$$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^x-1\over e^{ax}-1} dx=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\zeta(n)}{a^n}$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505573/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-zetankn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x-1}{e^{ax}-1} \, dx
&= \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x/a}-1}{e^{x}-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!a^n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^{x}-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!a^n} \Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(n+1)}{a^{n+1}},
\end{align*}

which confirms **@Did**'s answer. Also, $\text{(2)}$ is not valid as both integral diverges to infinity. An alternative expression can be found by applying the substitution $t = e^{-x}$:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x-1}{e^{ax}-1} \, dx
&= \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x/a}-1}{e^{x}-1} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^{-1/a}-1}{1-t} \, dt \\
&= - \frac{1}{a}\left(\gamma + \psi\left(1 - \frac{1}{a}\right) \right),
\end{align*}

where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

Comment: Can this sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\zeta(n+1)\over a^{n+1}}$ be evaluated @Sangchul Lee?

Comment: @NightOfPower, My second computation does give one such closed form. :)

Comment: @NightOfPower See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505573/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-zetankn