# How can I prove $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n)}{2^n}=\ln(2)$?

Tags: logarithms, riemann-zeta

Playing with values of $\zeta(n)$ in excel I find those two interesting results
$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n)}{2^n}=\ln(2)$$
$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n)}{(-2)^n}=1-\ln(2)$$
How is it obvious? How can I prove it?

Comment: The two sums diverge; perhaps you meant $2^{-n}$ resp. $(-2)^{-n}$?

Comment: @RedundantAunt, thank you for comment! I make a little (or big?) mistake.

Comment: Plug in $$\zeta(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n}$$ and change the order of summation.

Comment: Here is somehow related generalization of the question [Infinite Series $‎\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n)}{k^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505573/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-zetankn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using absolute convergence to justify changing the order of summation together with the sum of a geometric series:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(n)}{2^n} &= \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^n} \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^n} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac 1 {(2k)^n} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4k^2} \frac{1}{1 - \frac 1 {2k}} \\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k(2k - 1)} \\
&= \log 2
\end{align}

A similar argument works for the alternating sum.

Comment: Since all the terms involved are non-negative, there's not a possible concern for justifying interchange of sum.

Comment: Nobody uses that term that way

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(n)}{2^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^n}\\=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\Big)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...=\ln(1+1)=\ln 2$$
Analogue for the other sum. Note that interchange of the summations is justified by absolute convergence of the series involved.

Answer (score 1):

You may also exploit the integral representation for $\zeta(s)$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\zeta(n)}{2^n}&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!2^n(e^x-1)}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{x/2}-1}{2(e^x-1)}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^{x/2}+1}\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{e^z+1}=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{u(u+1)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{v+1}=\color{blue}{\log 2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$