# $\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{4^s}=\frac{\log 64 - \pi}{8}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

In my files found:
$$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{4^s}=\frac{\log 64 - \pi}{8}$$

And I assumed that this is something obvious. Now trying to prove this but can not.
Could you please suggest any simple way of proving this?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505573/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-2-infty-frac-zetankn?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{s=2}^{+\infty}\frac 1{4^s}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n^s}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum\limits_{s=2}^{+\infty}\frac 1{(4n)^s}=\frac 14\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n(4n-1)}=\frac 14\log 8-\frac {\pi}8$$

Comment: Thank you. It is really obvious after proof:)

Comment: Can you explain the last step (log8 and pi/2)?

Comment: @Conrad how is log(2)/2 = log(8)/4?

Comment: Oops - you are right