# How does the Herglotz trick work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> There is a [series representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_function#Series_definitions) as partial fraction expansion where just translated reciprocal functions are summed up, such that the poles of the cotangent function and the reciprocal functions match:
>      $$ \pi \cdot \cot (\pi x) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{x+n}. $$
>   This identity can be proven with the Herglotz trick.

Sounds funny, especially when you understand german (sorry [Gustav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Herglotz) ;-), but how does it work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Herglotz trick is basically to define
$$f(x):=\pi\cot\pi x,\quad g(x):=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{x+n}$$
and derive enough common properties of these functions to see in the end that they must coincide. Namely, it consists of showing that:

1. $f$ and $g$ are defined for all non-integral values and are continuous there.
2. They are periodic of period 1.
3. They are odd functions.
4. They satisfy the same functional relation $f(\frac{x}{2})+f(\frac{x+1}{2})=2f(x)$ and $g(\frac{x}{2})+g(\frac{x+1}{2})=2g(x)$.
5. By defining $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, and setting $h(x):=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $h$ becomes a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}$ that shares the properties given in (2), (3), and (4).

Now the "trick" is to use all these properties as follows. Since $h$ is a periodic continuous function, it possesses a maximum $m$. Let $x_0$ be a point in $[0,1]$ with $h(x_0)=m$. It follows from (4) that
$$h\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)+h\left(\frac{x_0+1}{2}\right)=2m,$$
and hence that $h(\frac{x_0}{2})=m$. Iteration gives $h(\frac{x_0}{2^n})=m$ for all $n$, and hence $h(0)=m$ by continuity. But $h(0)=0$, and so $m=0$, that is, $h(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. As $h(x)$ is an odd function, $h(x)<0$ is impossible, hence $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I took this from "Proofs from THE BOOK" by Aigner and Ziegler, where it is explained in details.

Comment: This post is very well written and instructive!  (+1)

Comment: It took _me_ a while to figure out why $h_0(\tfrac{x_0}2)$ had to equal $m$, though.

Comment: @AntonioDJC it took me a while, too. In case I have to return to this question: if $h(x_0/2)\neq m$ then $h(x_0/2)<m$ because $m$ is the maximum, so $$2m=2h(x_0)=h(x_0/2)+h(\frac{x_0+1}2)<2m$$.

Answer (score 5):

I give a pretty detailed proof [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179), but I am not sure what the Herglotz trick is.

I found a description of the Herglotz trick on the web and it seems to be the method I employed there. That is, look at enough similarities of the functions so that they have to be the same.

Comment: cool, thanks, +1 I'll upvote the linked answer...but it doesn't answer mine.

Comment: @draks...: I did look up the Herglotz trick just after your comment, and it was apparently what I used.  Was there more you needed?

Comment: no I'm fine now and we both learned something...