# The "trick" in the Herglotz trick

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations

In [How does the Herglotz trick work?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work), is explained as in  "Proofs from THE BOOK" by Aigner and Ziegler, but the "trick" itself I found to be not so clear.

The trick says:

> It follows from $(4)$ that $h\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)+h\left(\frac{x_0+1}{2}\right)=2m$,
> and hence that $h\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=m$.

But I can't understand why $h\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=m$, that implies $h\left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)=h\left(\frac{x_0+1}{2}\right)$, and I don't find anything that justifies this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did $h$ have maximum value $m$? That would explain the implication I think.