# Value of $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{6} \csc^{2}(\theta + \frac{k\pi}{7})}{7\csc^{2}(7\theta)}$

Tags: trigonometry

At $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

I  tried using Euler notation($e^{i\theta}$ form) but was of no help.I breaked the expression in parts but just to make it more cumbersome.

Any help !!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141715/evaluating-frac-sum-k-06-csc2a-frack-pi77-csc27a

Comment: This also appeared here at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154639/).

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Sorry i didnt know

Comment: @AbhashJha, Nothing to be sorry.