# Solving trigonometric series of $cosec^{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

$$\frac {\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{6} \operatorname{cosec}^{2}(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{7})}{7\operatorname{cosec}^{2}(7\theta)} = ?$$
Here, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$. This question is from a book recommended for JEE Advance exam.
I tried converting the series like, $$\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{7})}=\frac{2}{1-\cos(2\theta+\frac{2k\pi}{7})}$$
But this didn't lead to anything.
Then I also tried taking the $k=0$ term out and pair up first and last terms which still didn't lead to anything.
Hints or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Make it telescoping.

Comment: I tried to do that by turning it into cot but that also didn't help me. So could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's a book provided by my coaching institute so you might not be able to find it but it is the FIITJEE JEE Adv Review Package Part II.

Comment: Acha okay, Ill post my answer as soon as i get it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find $\frac{\sum_\limits{k=0}^{6}\csc^2\left(x+\frac{k\pi}{7}\right)}{7\csc^2(7x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154639/find-frac-sum-limitsk-06-csc2-leftx-frack-pi7-right7-csc27x) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B6%7D%5Coperatorname%7Bcosec%7D%5E%7B2%7D(%5Ctheta%2B%5Cfrac%7Bk%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D)%7D%7B7%5Coperatorname%7Bcosec%7D%5E%7B2%7D(7%5Ctheta)%7D%24&p=1). There are also other duplicates, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Evaluating $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^6 \csc^2(a+\frac{k\pi}{7})}{7\csc^2(7a)}$](/q/2141715), [Value of $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{6} \csc^{2}(\theta + \frac{k\pi}{7})}{7\csc^{2}(7\theta)}$](/q/2273307), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: oh yes it does help, and thanks. I have been helped by this community for a long time and now finally I am registered and will contribute!!