# Product Identity Multiple Angle or $\sin(nx)=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}n+x\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, products, angle

I have run across this interesting identity that I am unable to verify.

$$\sin(nx)=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}n+x\right)$$

Can anyone provide a hint as how one would prove this?

This identity was found on the Wolfram site[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html).

Comment: That "identity" fails for $n=1$.

Comment: You want to start at $k=0$, not $1$.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8385) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70231).

Comment: @lucian Not quite duplicates.  The appearance of the $x$ makes things a bit more complicated.

Comment: Similar question: [Proof of $\sin nx=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin\left( x + \frac{k\pi}{n} \right)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814527). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%5Csin%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bk%5Cpi%7Dn%2Bx%5Cright)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 12):

This solution herein is inspired by a comment left by @user1952009 on another posted solution.  That solution is elegant in that it relies on only $(i)$ Euler's formula to write

$$\sin(nx)=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}\tag 1$$

and $(ii)$ the $n$ roots of unity, $z=e^{-i2k \pi/n}$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$, of the equation $z^n=1$ to write

$$z^n-1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z-e^{-i2\pi k/n})\tag 2$$

Proceeding, we find

$$\begin{align}
\sin(nx)&=\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}&\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\left(e^{i2nx}-1\right)\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(e^{i2x}-e^{-i2\pi k/n})\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\color{blue}{e^{ix}}\color{red}{e^{-i\pi k/n}}\color{green}{(2i)}\sin\left(x+\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i} \color{blue}{e^{inx}} \color{red}{e^{-i(\pi/n)n(n-1)/2}}\color{green}{(2i)^n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(x+\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)\\\\
&=2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin\left(x+\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I failed to understand how you reached from $$\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\left(e^{i2nx}-1\right)\\\\$$ to
$$\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(e^{i2x-e^{-i2\pi k/n}})\\\\$$ and subsequent steps 
 Can you please explain a bit.

Comment: @navinstudent The equations in your comment have not been formatted

Comment: @navinstudent Look at Equation $(2)$.  Let $z=e^{i2x}$

Comment: Yes I see that . please do also clarify subsequent step.It really puzzled me.

Comment: Subsequent steps use straightforward arithmetic.  Are you familiar with Euler's Formula  in $(1)?

Comment: Yes I am very well aware of that

Comment: @navinstudent So, are you able to proceed then?

Comment: I think you meant $$\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(e^{i2x-e^{-i2\pi k/n}})\\\\$$ to be $$\frac{e^{-inx}}{2i}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(e^{i2x}-e^{-i2\pi k/n})\\\\$$.I am sorry I am not getting how you reached the next step despite mant tries.

Comment: @navinstudent Yes, of course.  Thanks for catching the typographical error.

Comment: Start by factoring $$e^{i2x}-e^{-i2\pi k/n}=e^{ix}e^{-i\pi k/n}\left(\cdot\right)$$What do you get?

Comment: Best Answer from those I have seen for this question

Comment: @maverick Thank you.  Much appreciative!

Comment: how did (2i)^n term disappear

Comment: @DDD4C4U The term $(2i)^n$ did not "disappear."  Note $(2i)^n=2^n e^{in\pi/2}$.  The note the term in red-colored font.

Comment: ah thank you now I understand

Comment: One more question, You have to wrote
 $$ z^n -1  = \prod_{k=0}^{k=n-1} (z- e^{ \frac{-2\pi k}{n}) $$ 

or, 

$$ z^n -1  = \prod_{k=0}^{k=n-1} (z- e^{ \frac{2\pi k}{n})$$.
 Now why did u prefer first instead of second? I tried using second way but I got a different result for same expresison

Comment: my latex is not rendering.. but I hope u understand

Comment: @DDD4C4U Those expressions, as far as I can understand them as written, are identical.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @MarkViola: unfortunately [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553495/121671) was deleted. Could you help me undelete it (2 more votes)? No problem if you can't.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I've clicked the undelete button

Answer (score 3):

You may prove such identity through Herglotz trick, for instance. Both the RHS and the LHS are entire functions in the complex plane of [order $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function), having simple zeroes at every point of $\frac{\pi}{n}\mathbb{Z}$ and only there. Additionally, they both are $\frac{2\pi}{n}$-periodic functions. It follows that such identity holds as soon as it holds for some $x\not\in\frac{\pi}{n}\mathbb{Z}$, like $x=\frac{\pi}{2n}$. In such a case, it is straightforward to prove through De Moivre's identity $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$.

Since $\sin(\pi z)=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)}$, you may also prove it through the [multiplication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem) for the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\sin z=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{\pi}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{z}{\pi}\right)}$.

Answer (score 2):

The right side is odd and periodic with period $2\pi/n$.  Repeated use of the identities for $\sin(a) \sin(b)$ and $\cos(a) \sin(b)$ must give you a sum of terms of the form $a_j \sin(j x)$ and $b_j \cos(j x)$ with $0 \le j \le n$, but the oddness and periodicity implies that the terms for $j < n$ and the $\cos$ terms cancel, leaving a multiple of $\sin(nx)$.    Now all you have to do is show that the constant is $1$...