# Inductive proof of Cotes' Theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, products

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\sin(nx) = 2^{n-1}\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \sin(x + i \cdot 180/n).$$

Other proofs use topics from complex analysis, but I am trying to prove this result using a purely geometric approach or with induction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [Robert Israel's suggestion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2095366)?

Comment: I'll give it a shot.