# A series identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x+k}$.

I need to show for every $x \in \mathbb{R}, x>0$:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x) = e\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!}$

What I have noticed: they have the same evaluation for $x=1$: they both go to $e-1$. Also, the left one is easy to evaluate for all natural numbers.

I'm quite sure there is some smart move with Taylor expansion, even though it doesnt't seem.

Comment: have you tried to take logarithms?

Comment: No, but how can you solve it that way? Logarithms well behave with products, not with sums, no?

Comment: i don'T claim this solves the problem, it is just an idea :-D

Answer (score 3):

We have $$S=\sum_{n\geq0}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\Gamma\left(x\right)}{\Gamma\left(x+1+n\right)}
 $$ $$=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}B\left(x,n+1\right)=\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(1-t\right)^{n}}{n!}dt=e\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt=\color{red}{e\gamma\left(x,1\right)}
 $$ where $\gamma\left(x,a\right)
 $ is the [incomplete Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html). The claim follows using the representation of $\gamma\left(x,a\right)$ as a [confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). Just for completeness $$S=ex^{-1}\,_{1}F_{1}\left(x;1+x;-1\right)=ex^{-1}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(x\right)_{n}}{\left(x+1\right)_{n}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}$$ $$=ex^{-1}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x\left(x+1\right)\cdots\left(x+n-1\right)}{\left(x+1\right)\cdots\left(x+n-1\right)\left(x+n\right)}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n!}=e\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(x+n\right)n!}.$$

Comment: Nice advanced math, step-by-step. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to check that the LHS and the RHS have the same residues at $x=0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots$

Obviously
$$\text{Res}\left(e\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!},x=-m\right)=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}e\tag{1} $$
while
$$ \text{Res}\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{x\cdots(x+n)},x=-m\right)=\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{k!}\tag{2}$$
that is exacty the same.

Comment: Can you link the theorem you used to conclude?

Comment: @ZenoCozeno: sure. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work

Comment: the functions can still differ by a constant right (which is zero in this case)?

Comment: @tired: of course, but the difference is zero by performing an explicit evaluation at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This was not an answer.

As a possible hint, observe that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}$$
and
$$f(x)-f(x+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{x(x+1)\cdots(x+n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n f_n(x)$$
On the other hand, we know that
$$f_n(x+1)=\prod_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x+k+1}=xf_{n+1}(x)$$
Consequently
$$f(x+1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x+1)=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=x f(x)-1$$
Thus
$$1+(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n f_n(x)$$

Let $g(t)=(1+t)^{-x}$ then
$$\mathcal {D_t}^n g(0)=(-1)^nx(x+1)\cdots(x+n)$$
I thought these relationships could be useful.