# Is there a summation to gamma transformation

Tags: hypergeometric-function

> **Question:** Is there a transformation you can use on a sum$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\text{something}$$To transform it into an expression with the gamma function? In other words, is this possible:$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\text{something}=\dfrac {\Gamma(\text{stuff})\Gamma(\text{stuff})\Gamma(\text{stuff})\cdots}{\Gamma(\text{stuff})\Gamma(\text{stuff})\cdots}$$

While trying to prove an identity, I got to$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {\left(\frac 12n+1\right)_k(n)_k(-x)_k(-y)_k}{\left(\frac 12n\right)_k(x+n+1)_k(y+n+1)_k}\dfrac {(-1)^k}{k!}\tag{1}$$
And according to the identity, $(1)$ is equal to$$\dfrac {\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma\left(x+y+n+1\right)}\tag{2}$$
So how to I start with $(1)$ and get $(2)$?

Comment: A Pochhammer symbol is $\frac{\Gamma(\text{stuff})}{\Gamma(\text{stuff})}$, hence $(1)=(2)$ follows by applying the residue theorem to the right function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So since $(a)_k=\Gamma(a+k)/\Gamma(a)$, apply the residue theorem and you get $(2)$?

Comment: I am skipping a lot of details, but essentially, yes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Looking at the wikipedia page, I still don't understand how to apply the residue theorem to a summation. Could you elaborate or write an answer please? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $k\geq 0$, $\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ is exactly the residue of the function $\Gamma(z)$ at $z=-k$.
It follows that the given series can be written as

$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(n+2k)\Gamma(n+k)\Gamma(-x+k)\Gamma(-y+k)\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n+k+1)\Gamma(y+n+k+1)\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(-y)}\cdot\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} $$
and we "just" have to show that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(n+2k)\Gamma(n+k)\Gamma(-x+k)\Gamma(-y+k)}{\Gamma(x+n+k+1)\Gamma(y+n+k+1)\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(-y)}\cdot\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=\Gamma(x+y+n+1) \tag{1}$$
That seems an impossible task through integral transforms or similar techniques, but the [Herglotz' trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work) makes it easy. We may consider the RHS of $(1)$ as a meromorphic function of $x$ for fixed values of $y$ and $n$, locate its poles and compute its residues. We may do the same for every term appearing in the LHS of $(1)$, deriving that both the LHS and the RHS of $(1)$ have the same singularities (simple poles) with the same residues. By proving $(1)$ for a specific value of $x$ like $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we get that $(1)$ holds as an identity as soon as the LHS is a convergent series.

This kind of *structure tricks* allows us to prove many interesting identities , like Ramanujan's identities for the [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) $E_4,E_6,E_8$.

Comment: Is it possible if you include the work for the Herglotz' trick? This math is way over my head... :/

Comment: It is not difficult to get material about the Herglotz trick by following the link and performing a little googling.