# Cauchy product of 2 series

Tags: cauchy-product

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I want to prove that

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n} \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^n}{z-n} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}.$$

Using the Cauchy Product I get
$$\sum_{n \in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(z-k)}\frac{1}{(z-n-k)}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: You are multiplying two conditionally convergent series. Good luck!

Comment: Are you aware that the RHS is $\left(\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}\right)^2$ ? (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314968)

Comment: For the LHS, see (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344144)

Comment: No comment ?...

Comment: Still no comment, a day after ? This site is based on exchanges, don't forget it. I had forgotten to mention that the RHS can be writen $(\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x))^2$ (see "complements formula")