# sum of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{k^2+a^{2}}, \ \ \sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{(k-1/2)^2+a^{2}}
\end{equation}
be summed explicitly, where $a$ is a constant real number? Can any one give me some hint or tell me that the analytic expression doesn't exist. Thanks very much!

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2+a^2}=\frac{1+a\pi\cdot\text{csch }(a\pi)}{2a^2}\qquad;\qquad\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2-a^2}=-\frac{1+a\pi\cdot\csc(a\pi)}{2a^2}$$

Comment: Maple can give closed forms for the sums. I have not tried Mathematics though.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: they hopefully look like my answer.

Comment: @robjohn: Maple gives the answers in terms of the digamma function as yours, however you can simplify further.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: the answer to the second sum is in terms of the digamma function; the first sum is in terms of the hyperbolic cosecant function.

Comment: @robjohn: I can see this. The second one, maple can simplify it as a mixed expression in terms of Psi and elemetary functions.

Comment: See related sums and their relations to the digamma function starting on [page 96](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: The second sum without the alternating signs can be written as a function of the hyperbolic tangent, but then we still need to use digamma to bring back the alternation. Depending on your preferences, that might be simpler or not since it still involves digamma.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I have added a second form of the second sum using the idea above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use equation $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179):
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{k+z}=\pi\cot(\pi z)\tag{1}
$$
Directly from $(1)$, we have
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac2{2k+z}=\pi\cot(\pi z/2)\tag{2}
$$
Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\csc(\pi z)
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+z}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1z-2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2-z^2}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $z\mapsto iz$ in $(4)$ gives
$$
\pi\,\mathrm{csch}(\pi z)
=\frac1z+2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2+z^2}\tag{5}
$$
This works nicely to give us the first sum:
$$
\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2+z^2}
=\frac{\pi z\,\mathrm{csch}(\pi z)+1}{2z^2}}\tag{6}
$$

---

Substituting $z\mapsto z+\frac12$ in $(3)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\sec(\pi z)
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac12+z}\tag{7}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{\left(k+\frac12\right)^2-z^2}\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $z\mapsto iz$ in $(8)$ gives
$$
\pi\,\mathrm{sech}(\pi z)
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{\left(k+\frac12\right)^2+z^2}\tag{9}
$$
This fails to give us the second sum because we have to add $\frac1{k+\frac12+z}$ and $\frac1{k+\frac12-z}$ instead of subtracting them because of the alternating signs. So we have to resort to another approach.

---

The [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
$$
\psi(x)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+x}\right)\tag{10}
$$
is the derivative of the logarithm of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
$$
\psi\left(-\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(-\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)
=4iz\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(2k-\frac12\right)^2+z^2}\tag{11}
$$
and
$$
\psi\left(\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)
=4iz\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(2k+\frac12\right)^2+z^2}\tag{12}
$$
Subtracting $(12)$ from $(11)$ yields the second sum:
$$
\begin{align}
&\hspace{-1cm}\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+z^2}}\\[6pt]
&\hspace{-1cm}\color{#C00000}{=\frac1{4iz}\left(\psi\left(-\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(-\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)+\psi\left(\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)\right)}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$

---

The second sum without alternation can be achieved by substituting $z\mapsto z-\frac12$ in $(1)$:
$$
\begin{align}
-\pi\tan(\pi z)
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k-\frac12+z}\tag{14}\\
&=-2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2-z^2}\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting $z\mapsto iz$ in $(15)$ yields
$$
\pi\tanh(\pi z)=2z\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+z^2}\tag{16}
$$
Thus, we get the second sum without alternation
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+z^2}
=\frac4{4z^2+1}+\frac{\pi\tanh(\pi z)}{2z}\tag{17}
$$
From $(12)$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{\left(2k+\frac12\right)^2+z^2}
=\frac1{2iz}\left(\psi\left(\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)\right)\tag{18}
$$
Subtracting $(18)$ from $(17)$ yields an alternate form for the second sum:
$$
\begin{align}
&\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(k-\frac12\right)^2+z^2}}\\[6pt]
&\color{#C00000}{=\frac4{4z^2+1}+\frac{\pi\tanh(\pi z)}{2z}-\frac1{2iz}\left(\psi\left(\frac14+\frac{iz}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac14-\frac{iz}{2}\right)\right)}\tag{19}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that
$$\csc z = \frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z^2 - k^2 \pi^2}.$$
Changing $z$ into $\pi z$ produces
$$\pi\csc(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z^2 - k^2}, \quad z \ne n \pi, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z},$$
so
$$\frac{\pi\csc(\pi z) - 1/z}{2z} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z^2 - k^2}.$$
Then it can be shown, by replacing $z$ with $iz$ and using $\csc(iz) = -i\operatorname{cosech} z$, that
$$\operatorname{cosech} z = \frac{1}{z} + 2z\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z^2 + k^2}, \quad z \ne n \pi i, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z},$$
or
$$\frac{\pi\operatorname{cosech}(\pi z) - 1/z}{2z} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{z^2 + k^2}.$$

The second series looks familiar, but I cannot remember what it equals.

Comment: The $k=0$ term is missing, but otherwise, this gives the correct answer for the first sum.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{k^2+a^{2}}$$
This series [converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+from+k%3D0+to+infty+of+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28+-1%5Cright%29+%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%7Bk%5E2%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D) to
$$\dfrac{1}{2a^2}+\dfrac{\pi\mathrm{csch}(\pi a)}{2a}$$
Now,
$$\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{(k-1/2)^2+a^{2}}$$
This series also [converges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum+from+k%3D0+to+infty+of+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28+-1%5Cright%29+%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%7B%28k-1%2F2%29%5E2%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D) by the comparison test.

Now,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k= 0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{k^2+a^{2}}+ \frac{\left( -1\right) ^{k}}{(k-1/2)^2+a^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}
Use the [comparison test](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%3D0+to+infinity+of+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28+-1%5Cright%29+%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%7Bk%5E2%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D%2B+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28+-1%5Cright%29+%5E%7Bk%7D%7D%7B%28k-1%2F2%29%5E2%2Ba%5E%7B2%7D%7D) to see that this is convergent.

Comment: I think the asker wanted to find explicitely the sum of each series (individually), rather than just show that they are convergent.  I could have misunderstood though

Comment: @Hayden Maybe. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Hayden See my edited answer.

Comment: Are you sure about the divergence of the sum? Wolfram alpha says it converges by the comparison test.

Comment: @DavidH My mistake - I wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: The sum of two convergent series is convergent, you don't need to check for convergence a third time.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff True... That *was* a bit redundant - should I remove it?