# Series identity for cotangent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form

How to prove that $x \cot(x) = 1 - 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2}}{(n \pi)^{2}-x^{2}}}$?

First, it does not seem to be solvable, using considerations regarding Taylor series. The Fourier approach also is not effective enough (i should also take into consideration that $x \cot(x)$ has infinite discontinuites, so it narrows expansion to the interval, where the function behaves well).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can start with the infinite product expression $\frac{\sin\,\pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$, take $\log$ on both sides and differentiate w.r.t. $x$, or see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179/129017) for a nice solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the sum of $\sum 1/(k^2 - a^2)$ when $0&lt;a&lt;1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1)