# Is every series that matters a Taylor series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, fourier-series

Fourier series are Taylor series in complex z, so I'm wondering if there is *any* kind of series that represents analytic almost everywhere functions that is foundationally distinct from Taylor series?

Or is every series that matters for analytic functions a Taylor series?

Comment: This has a Taylor Series but it's meaningless https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "0 replies 0 retweets 0 likes" but I think that question would be equivalent to asking "Are there any basis of the space of complex analytical functions that are not polynomial in nature?"

Comment: I asked this on math twitter at first and didn't get a response. removed the "retweets" stuff.

Comment: Try Dirichlet series! They show up all the time when studying zeta-functions and $L$-functions, and they are analytic in a (right) half-plane, but these series are not power series.

Comment: Lambert series are interesting and important also.

Comment: And there's the famous series for cotangent, which there are many questions about on this site, for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308948/series-identity-for-cotangent

Comment: "Fourier series are Taylor series in complex z," I'm not sure what that means. "analytic almost everywhere functions " Not sure about that either.

Comment: holomorphic except at a countable set of point. "AAEF"

Comment: http://dev.ipol.im/~coco/website/taylorfourier.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about the Riemann zeta function?
$$
\zeta(s):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}n^{-s}\qquad \operatorname{re} s>1
$$

This is manifestly *not* a Taylor series, yet it is analytic on its domain of definition (and can be continued to all $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$).

See also [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series), [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), etc.

Comment: OK, but that is not an example of what the OP is calling an "almost everywhere analytic function"

Comment: @zhw. You'll have to elaborate. I do think it is a perfectly good example of what OP is looking for.

Comment: The OP wanted an "almost everywhere analytic function", which the OP in a comment defined as a function analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus E,$ where $E$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb C.$

Comment: @zhw. I'm not sure where that comment is, but anyway. I don't think that is relevant to my example: the Riemann zeta function is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, even if the particular representation above is only valid for $\mathrm{re}\, s>1$. There are other series representations that converge everywhere away from the singularity.

Comment: It's the second to last comment of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There are also the series $$\sum_{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}} \frac{1}{(a\tau + b)^{2k}},$$ where $k \geq 2$.  Though these converge on the open set Im$(\tau) > 0$.  They are important in the theories of modular forms and elliptic functions.  They satisfy infinitely many
[symmetries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form) !

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z) = 1/z$ in $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}.$ Note $f(z)$ equals the infinite series $f(z) + 0+0+0+\cdots$ everywhere in its domain. But it can't equal a power series in this domain, because such a power series would have to converge in all of $\mathbb C.$ This would imply $f$ has a removable singularity at $0,$ contradiction.