# How to compute $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^5}dx$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

> Let $\phi$ denote the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$.
>   How can I prove this sum?
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left[\frac{\phi}{(5n+1)^2}+\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+2)^2}-\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+3)^2}-\frac{\phi}{(5n+4)^2}\right]=\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right)^2$$

My try:

Change  the sums into an integrals:
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(5n+1)^2}=\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(x)}{1+x^5}dx$

**Can somebody give a hint how on to integrate this integral.**

Try substitution by letting $u=\ln(x)$ is not working and integration by part is making it more complicated than before. What kind of substitution should I be using?

Comment: Maple returns an extremely complicated closed form for the integral.

Comment: Is there another way of proving the series with different method?

Comment: @adambui 
yes, see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac12(3x^2-1)$ for $x\in(-1,1)$ and its periodic extension with period $2$. Since $f(x)=f(-x)$ we can write
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos n\pi x$$
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac12(3x^2-1)dx=0=2a_0$$
$$\begin{align}\int_{-1}^1\frac12(3x^2-1)\cos n\pi x\,dx&=\left[\frac1{n\pi}\frac12(3x^2-1)\sin n\pi x+\frac{3x}{n^2\pi^2}\cos n\pi x-\frac3{n^3\pi^3}\sin n\pi x\right]_{-1}^1\\
&=\frac{6(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}=a_n\end{align}$$
So
$$f(x)=\frac6{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos n\pi x$$
Note that $\cos\left(n\pi\left(1-\frac15\right)\right)=(-1)^n\cos\frac{n\pi}5$. So
$$\begin{align}f\left(\frac45\right)&=\frac{23}{50}=\frac6{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}\cos\frac{n\pi}5\\
&=\frac6{\pi^2}\left(\frac{\sigma}2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{25n^2}(-1)^n\right)\\
&=\frac6{\pi^2}\left(\frac{\sigma}2+\frac1{25}\left(-\frac12\right)\frac{\pi^2}6\right)\end{align}$$
Here $\sigma$ is the topical sum, where the coefficient of $1/n^2$ is $2\cos n\pi/5$ except where $n=5k$ where the $\cos 5k\pi/5=(-1)^k$ has been omitted. Thus
$$\sigma=2\frac{\pi^2}6\left(\frac{23}{50}+\frac1{50}\right)=\frac{4\pi^2}{25}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{5}}\,\dd x &=
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\pars{{1 \over 1 + x^{5}} + {1 \over 1 - x^{5}}}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x^{5}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x^{10}}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x^{5}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over 50}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,x^{-9/10}\,\dd x -
{1 \over 25}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,x^{-4/5}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 50}\lim_{\mu \to -9/10}\totald{}{\mu}
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1} + \gamma}}\ +\
{1 \over 25}\lim_{\mu \to -4/5}\totald{}{\mu}
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1} + \gamma}}
\\[3mm] & =
\fbox{$\ds{{1 \over 50}\bracks{%
           2\Psi\,'\pars{{1 \over 5}} - \Psi\,'\pars{{1 \over 10}}}}$}
\approx -0.9780
\end{align}

$\Psi\pars{z}$ is the **digamma function** and $\gamma$ is the **Euler-Mascheroni constant**. The final integral which involves the $\Psi$ function is a 'standard' identity and it appears in, for example, Abramowitz and Stegun table.

Comment: the simplicity of this answer is beautiful! I'm glad you're back in action.

Comment: @etothepitimesi Thanks. I was being very busy.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the sum we are looking for with $S$.

Furthermore, notice that ($k \in [1,4] $)

$$
S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(5n+k)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(5(2n)+k)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(5(2n+1)+k)^2}=\\
\frac{1}{5^22^2}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+k/10)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+(k+5)/10)^2}\right]=\\
\frac{1}{5^22^2}\left[\psi^{(1)}(k/10)-\psi^{(1)}((k+5)/10)\right]
$$

where we used the definition of the [Trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function)

Taking now for example $\Delta_{14}=S_1-S_4$

$$
\Delta_{14} =\frac{1}{5^22^2}\left[\psi^{(1)}(1/10)-\psi^{(1)}(6/10)\right]-\frac{1}{5^22^2}\left[\psi^{(1)}(4/10)-\psi^{(1)}(9/10)\right]=
\frac{1}{5^22^2}(\psi^{(1)}(1/10)+\psi^{(1)}(9/10))-\frac{1}{5^22^2}(\psi^{(1)}(4/10)+\psi^{(1)}(6/10))
$$

Trigamma reflection [$\psi^{(1)}(1-z)+\psi^{(1)}(z)=\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function) yields the massive simplification

$$
\Delta_{14}=\frac{\pi^2}{100}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(\pi/10)}-\frac{1}{\sin^2(4\pi/ 10)}\right)=\\
\frac{\pi^2}{125}(5+3\sqrt{5})
$$

Playing the same game with $\Delta_{23}=S_2-S_3$ we obtain

$$
\Delta_{23}=\frac{\pi^2}{125}(-5+3\sqrt{5})
$$

Doing the algebra yields

> $$
> S=\phi\Delta_{14}+\frac{\Delta_{23}}{\phi}=\frac{4 \pi^2}{25}\\
> \bf{QED}
> $$

Comment: In the same spirit, we could use the fact that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(an+b)^2}=\frac{\zeta \left(2,\frac{b}{2 a}\right)-\zeta \left(2,\frac{a+b}{2 a}\right)}{4
   a^2}$$ and do the same with reflection formulae.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left[\frac{\phi}{(5n+1)^{2}}-\frac{\phi}{(5n+4)^{2}}\right] & =\frac{2}{125}\left(5+2\sqrt{5}\right)\pi^{2}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left[\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+2)^{2}}-\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+3)^{2}}\right] & =\frac{2}{125}\left(5-2\sqrt{5}\right)\pi^{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: how do u get this result?

Comment: Nice answer, prove?

Comment: You can do it yourself if you read up on the trigamma function.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function

Answer (score 0):

**Requested integral**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{-\log(x)}{1+x^5}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{1+e^{-5u}}\,e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(e^{-u}-e^{-6u}+e^{-11u}-e^{-16u}+\dots\right)u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\Gamma(2)\left(1-\frac1{6^2}+\frac1{11^2}-\frac1{16^2}+\dots\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{e^{\pi i(k-1)/5}+e^{3\pi i(k-1)/5}+e^{5\pi i(k-1)/5}+e^{7\pi i(k-1)/5}+e^{9\pi i(k-1)/5}}{5k^2}\\
&=\tfrac{e^{-\pi i/5}}5\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{\pi i/5}\right)
+\tfrac{e^{-3\pi i/5}}5\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{3\pi i/5}\right)
+\tfrac{e^{-5\pi i/5}}5\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{5\pi i/5}\right)
+\tfrac{e^{-7\pi i/5}}5\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{7\pi i/5}\right)
+\tfrac{e^{-9\pi i/5}}5\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{9\pi i/5}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac25\operatorname{Re}\left(
e^{-\pi i/5}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{\pi i/5}\right)
+e^{-3\pi i/5}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(e^{3\pi i/5}\right)
\right)
+\frac{\pi^2}{60}\\[6pt]
&=0.9779708947989040114122103535270704097171
\end{align}
$$

---

**Full Sum**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179/13854), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+k}=\pi\cot(\pi z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{z+k}
&=\overbrace{2\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+2k}}^{\text{twice the even terms}}
-\overbrace{\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{z+k}}^{\text{all the terms}}\\
&=\pi\cot(\pi z/2)-\pi\cot(\pi z)\\[9pt]
&=\pi\csc(\pi z)
\end{align}
$$
Taking the derivative yields
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(z+k)^2}
=\pi^2\csc(\pi z)\cot(\pi z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac1{(5n+1)^2}-\frac1{(5n+4)^2}\right]
&=\frac1{25}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(n+\frac15\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{25}\csc\left(\frac\pi5\right)\cot\left(\frac\pi5\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi^2}{125}\sqrt{70+30\sqrt5}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac1{(5n+2)^2}-\frac1{(5n+3)^2}\right]
&=\frac1{25}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\left(n+\frac25\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{25}\csc\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\pi^2}{125}\sqrt{70-30\sqrt5}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left[\frac\phi{(5n+1)^2}+\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+2)^2}-\frac{\phi^{-1}}{(5n+3)^2}-\frac{\phi}{(5n+4)^2}\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{25}\frac{\left(1+\sqrt5\right)\sqrt{7+3\sqrt5}+\left(-1+\sqrt5\right)\sqrt{7-3\sqrt5}}{\sqrt{10}}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^2}{25}\frac{\sqrt{9+4\sqrt5}+\sqrt{9-4\sqrt5}}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{2\pi^2}{25}\frac{\left(2+\sqrt5\right)+\left(-2+\sqrt5\right)}{\sqrt5}\\
&=\frac{4\pi^2}{25}
\end{align}
$$