# Infinite sum and the conditions with tanh

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Is there a way to prove this relation?:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{s}^2+\left(1+2\text{n}\right)^2\omega^2}=\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\text{s}}{2\omega}\right)}{4\text{s}\omega}$$

And find the conditions for which this equality hold?

Comment: hint1: mittag leffler theorem. hint2: product representation of $\sin$. hint3: contour integration

Comment: @tired I do not know anything about those three hints:(

Comment: then consult the internet

Comment: learn something about this topics, and sharpen your question afterwards

Comment: @tired I want to learn those of course, and maybe you can give me an introduction by helping me with the answer :)

Comment: i give you a starting point: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1/143179#143179

Comment: Besides the very great hint given by @tired I would suggest you to read and study: " Complex Variables, theory and applications " by Murray S. Spiegel, in which you will learn about infinite series, residues, complex variables, contour integration et cetera. After that, I bet you'll be able to solve that.

Comment: There ought to be a more real analysis approach.

Comment: @SimpleArt There "ought" to be? It might be, but trust me, complex analysis is ways easier and faster in the most of cases, especially when it's about problems like that.

Comment: @AlanTuring I agree, but the OP probably has no experience with such, and "learning real quick" is not quite possible, even just conceptually.

Comment: @SimpleArt The problem is that it sound strange to me that he has to evaluate that with Real Analysis. Sure it has to be possible, but.. quite sadistic, isn't it? :D

Comment: @AlanTuring the story of my life.

Comment: @SimpleArt lol. Pass to the complex side! We have imaginary $\pi$ :D :D

Comment: @AlanTuring $\sqrt{-1}\ 2^3\ \sum\ \pi$, and it was delicious.

Comment: @SimpleArt LOL!

Comment: But this does not help me :(

Comment: have you figured it out?

Comment: @tired No I don't. What I've done is looking at the series expansion of $\tanh$ but I don't get it.

Comment: do you know contour integration?

Comment: @tired I've looked at it but it is hard to understand without any explaning

Comment: have you read this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration

Comment: @tired Sure I did.

Comment: Point is that in point of view the simplest way of proving this is to integrate 
$$
f(z)=\tan(\pi z /2)/(\alpha^2+z^2)
$$

around a circle with radius $R$ in the complex plane (Note that $f(z)\sim 1/z^2$ for large enough $|z|$). I invite to think about this approach

Comment: @tired I've no idea, maybe you can give me a start in an answer?!

Answer (score 3):

A real-analytic derivation through Fourier series.

---

You may remove a useless parameter by setting $s=\omega t$ then look for a closed form for
$$ S(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{t^2+(2n+1)^2}\tag{1} $$
Integration by parts gives a useful lemma:
$$ \forall a,b>0,\qquad\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(a x)}{a} e^{-bx}\,dx = \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\tag{2} $$
and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}=W(x)\tag{3} $$
is a $2\pi$-periodic rectangle wave that equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$ over $(0,\pi)$ and $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ over $(\pi,2\pi)$.
 By exploiting $(2)$ and $(3)$,
$$ S(t) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}W(x) e^{-tx}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}e^{-tx}\,dx\tag{4}$$
and by computing the last integrals and the resulting geometric series,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{t^2+(2n+1)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4t}\,\tanh\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)}\tag{5}$$
follows. The same can be achieved through the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Answer (score 1):

Using [the identity](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{Residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)\textrm{ at }f'\textrm{s poles}\right\} $$ which follows from the residue theorem we have $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{s^{2}+\left(2n+1\right)^{2}\omega^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{s^{2}+\left(2n+1\right)^{2}\omega^{2}}$$ and since we have poles at $z=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i\sqrt{s^{2}}}{2\sqrt{\omega^{2}}}$ we can conclude that $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{s^{2}+\left(2n+1\right)^{2}\omega^{2}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi s}{2\omega}\right)}{4s\omega}}$$ as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{\mrm{n} = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \mrm{s}^{2} + \pars{1 + 2\mrm{n}}^{2}\omega^{2}} =
{1 \over 4\omega^{2}}\sum_{\mrm{n} = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{\mrm{n} + 1/2}^{2} + \mrm{s}^{2}/\pars{4\omega^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4\omega^{2}}\sum_{\mrm{n} = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over
\bracks{\mrm{n} + 1/2 + \mrm{s}\,\ic\,/\pars{2\omega}}
\bracks{\mrm{n} + 1/2 - \mrm{s}\,\ic\,/\pars{2\omega}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4\omega^{2}}\,
{\Psi\pars{1/2 + \mrm{s}\,\ic\,/\bracks{2\omega}} -
\Psi\pars{1/2 - \mrm{s}\,\ic\,/\bracks{2\omega}}\over \mrm{s}\,\ic\,/\omega}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{\ic \over 4\,\mrm{s}\omega}\,
\bracks{\pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} - {\mrm{s} \over 2\omega}\,\ic}}} =
-\,{\pi\ic \over 4\,\mrm{s}\omega}\,
\tan\pars{{\pi\,\mrm{s} \over 2\omega}\,\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\pi\ic \over 4\,\mrm{s}\omega}\,
\bracks{\ic\tanh\pars{\pi\,\mrm{s} \over 2\omega}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{\pi \over 4\,\mrm{s}\omega}\,
\tanh\pars{\pi\,\mrm{s} \over 2\omega}}} \\ &
\end{align}