# How to prove that this series converges and for which conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that this series converges? $\exists\space\text{s}\space\wedge\space\exists\space\omega\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=0}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{s}^2+\left(1+2\text{n}\right)^2\omega^2}$$

Comment: What are $\;s,w\;$? Complex numbers, real numbers, ducks...?

Comment: Assume that they are complex numbers. And yes also ducks :) #LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\;s.w\in\Bbb C\;$ , we can write:

$$\left|\frac1{s^2+(1+2n)^2w^2}\right|=\frac1{|s^2+(1+2n)^2w^2|}\le\frac1{(1+2n)^2|w|^2-|s|^2}$$

and since the series with the rightmost general term converges then so does absolutely your series...of course, assuming $\;w\neq0\;$ .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the name of proving that a series converges this way? And how can I prove the inequality?

Comment: @asdasd (1) Comparison test , (2) This is a basic property of the complex modulus: $\;|z+w|\ge|z|-|w|\;$ .

Comment: But what about $\Im(\omega)=0$ and $\Re(\omega)<0$?

Comment: @asdasd Why should I care about that? In that case we *also* have $\;|w|^2>0\;$ , of course.

Comment: Haha yes TRUE!!

Comment: @DonAntonio Shouldn't you take $(1 + 2n)^2|w|^2 - |s|^2$ as denominator? Note that your denominator is negative for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @Dominik Nice question!!!??

Comment: @Dominik You're indeed right,  thanks...though the convergence fact isn't affected by this. I shall edit, though.

Comment: Well, if the term is negative then the inequality does not hold ($a < b <0$ implies $1/a < 1/b < 0$). So this does indeed have an impact.

Comment: @Dominik Read what I wrote: the fact of convergence isn't affected. Certainly all the rest must be fixed...and it is, now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we can also calculate the closed form of this series. We have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{z^{2}+(1+2n)^{2}}=2\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{z^{2}+\left(1+2n\right)^{2}}$$ and now we can use the [well known summation formula](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi w\right)f\left(w\right)\textrm{ at }f\left(w\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} 
 $$ and now since we have poles at $\frac{1}{2}i\left(z\pm i\right)
 $ we get $$-\textrm{Res}_{w=-\frac{i\left(z-i\right)}{2}}\pi\cot\left(\pi w\right)f\left(w\right)-\textrm{Res}_{w=\frac{i\left(z+i\right)}{2}}\pi\cot\left(\pi w\right)f\left(w\right)=\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}{2z}
 $$ hence $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{z^{2}+\left(1+2n\right)^{2}}=\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}{4z}$$ now taking $z=s/\omega
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{s^{2}+\left(1+2n\right)^{2}\omega^{2}}=\color{green}{\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi s}{2\omega}\right)}{4\omega s}}.$$for $\omega\neq0$ and $s\neq0$.

Comment: When I asked Mathematice I got that the sum equals $\frac{\pi\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\text{s}}{2\omega}\right)}{4\text{s}\omega}$. So you got the same as me (for the tanh part) but you've $-\frac{1}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}$ extra. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022848/infinite-sum-and-the-conditions-with-tanh

Comment: @asdasd My series starts from $n=1.$

Comment: I dont actually see what you mean, so can you maybe write the same proof but then with the starting point $\text{n}=0$?

Comment: @asdasd The "extra term" is only the value of the series at $n=0$. For some unknown reason I read that $n$ starts from $1$ instead of $0$ in your question. The proof is the same, you have only to observe that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{z^{2}+(1+2n)^{2}}=2\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{z^{2}+\left(1+2n\right)^{2}}.$$

Comment: I see it, but when you've the time and if you want to help me can you rewrite your answer,by starting at $\text{n}=0$?! Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @asdasd I changed my answer, but I think you have not understood my proof.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $ \omega \ne 0$.

We have

$\frac{1}{\text{s}^2+\left(1+2\text{n}\right)^2\omega^2} \le \frac{1}{4n^2 \omega^2}$.

Comment: And what about $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$? And if the inequality is right how can I prove that?

Comment: This inequality makes no sense in $\;\Bbb C\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio That's what I thought

Comment: @asdasd Yet you should write *in your question* that $\;s,w\in\Bbb C\;$ , otherwise people could simply assume they are real...