# Series representation of hyperbolic cotangent

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

I recently encountered this series representation of hyperbolic cotangent function. How this equation can be derived?
$$\coth(z) =\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z}{z^{2}+k^{2}\pi^{2}}, \quad
\frac{iz}{\pi} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the sum can be written as
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{z}{z^{2}+k^{2}\pi^{2}}=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}+k^{2}\pi^{2}}$$
From Euler's formula for the trigonometric cotangent (see e.g. [Find the sum of $\sum 1/(k^2 - a^2)$ when $0<a<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1) or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cotangent.html, formula (18))
$$\pi \cot \pi z=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}-k^{2}}$$
you find
$$\cot z=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}-k^{2}\pi^{2}}$$
Now use $\cot z = i \coth(iz)$ to get

$\begin{align*}
\coth(z) &= -i\cot(-iz)\\
&= -i\left(\frac{1}{-iz}+2(-iz)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(-zi)^{2}-k^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{z}-2z\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{-z^{2}-k^{2}\pi^{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{z}+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{2}+k^{2}\pi^{2}}
\end{align*}$