# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}$ and other sums of quadratic reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

What is the exact value for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}$$ and can other infinite sums of quadratic reciprocals have specific values.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}$$ and if the difference between $a$ and $b$ is an integer or half an integer, or both $a,b$ lie in $\mathbb{Q}$, the RHS simplifies. Here $\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}.$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Infinite Sum**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n^2+n+1}
&=\frac1{i\sqrt3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{n+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2}-\frac1{n+\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2}\right]\tag1\\
&=\frac1{i\sqrt3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{n+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2}+\frac1{-n-\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2}\right]\tag2\\
&=\frac1{i\sqrt3}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{n+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2}\tag3\\
&=\frac1{i\sqrt3}\pi\cot\left(\frac\pi2-i\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)\tag4\\
&=\frac1{i\sqrt3}\pi\tan\left(i\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)\tag5\\
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: partial fractions
$(2)$: rewrite second term
$(3)$: write as a principal value sum
$(4)$: $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179)
$(5)$: $\cot\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\tan(x)$
$(6)$: $\tan(ix)=i\tanh(x)$

Therefore,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+n+1}=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)-1}\tag7
$$

---

**Derivation of Claude Leibovici's Asymptotic Expansion**

Since we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n^2+n+1}
&=\frac1{n^2}\frac{1-\frac1n}{1-\frac1{n^3}}\\
&=\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^3}+\frac1{n^5}-\frac1{n^6}+\frac1{n^8}-\frac1{n^9}+\frac1{n^{11}}-\frac1{n^{12}}\cdots\tag8
\end{align}
$$
Applying the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to $(8)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2+k+1}\\
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)-1\\
&-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}-\frac2{3n^3}+\frac{11}{15n^5}-\frac1{n^6}+\frac1{3n^7}+\frac1{n^8}-\frac8{5n^9}+\frac{83}{33n^{11}}-\frac1{n^{12}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{13}}\right)\tag9
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can any quadratic be factored out like that?

Comment: @AbhishekAb: The quadratic formula will allow us to factor any quadratic

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment.*

Starting with limit given by robjohn, it seems that we can get quite good approximation of the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)-1-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{2}{3 p^3}+\frac{11}{15
   p^5}-\frac{1}{p^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^7}\right)$$

For $n=10$, the exact result is $\frac{13212635038}{18675445971}\approx 0.7074869890$ while the above expansion gives $\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\tanh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt3}2\right)-\frac{3271981}{3000000}\approx 0.7074869472$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the mechanics of partial sums, could you by chance comment a link for it.

Answer (score 2):

According to Maple,

$$ \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \tanh \left(\frac{\pi \sqrt{3}}{2}\right) - 1 $$

It looks like all the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+tn+1}$ for integers $t\ne -2 $ have closed forms.

EDIT: Here are a few examples:

$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{ {n}^{2}+n+1} & =\frac{\pi \tanh(\pi \sqrt{3}/2)}{\sqrt{3}}-1\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+n+1} &= \frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+3n+1} &= \frac{\pi \tan(\pi \sqrt{5}/2)}{\sqrt{5}}\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+4n+1} &= -\frac{\pi \cot(\pi \sqrt{3})}{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{3}\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+5n+1} &= \frac{\pi \tan(\pi \sqrt{21}/2)}{\sqrt{21}}-\frac{7}{15}\cr
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+6n+1} &= -\frac{\pi\cot(2 \sqrt{2}\pi)}{4\sqrt{2}}-\frac{61}{112}}$$

Comment: What if you changed the coefficient of n?

Comment: Just out of curiosity (since I don't hav any access to Maple) : could you provide the result for a few values of $t$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: It seems, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+bn+c} = \frac{\pi \tan\big(\frac{\pi}2\sqrt{b^2-4c}\big)}{\sqrt{b^2-4c}}$$ where, like in the OP's post, we use $\tanh x = -i\tan(ix)$ when $b^2-4c<0$. (The case $b=2,\,c=1$ is a special case.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Thanks.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That's not quite right: there's a rational term you left out.

Comment: Also, if $b$ is even it's $-\cot$ rather than $\tan$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Oops, mea culpa. The formula above (which starts at $n=0$) is only for the special case when $b=1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I've asked a general question in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580695/on-sum-n-0-infty-frac1n2bnc-frac-pi-tan-big-frac-pi2-sqrtb) regarding that missing rational term.