How to evaluate this infinite series :$1+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}+....$
How to evaluate this infinite series :$$S=1+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}+....=1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^k}{(4k+3)(4k+5)}$$
therfore:
$$S-1=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^k}{(4k+3)(4k+5)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k-1)(4k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k-1)}-\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k+1)}$$
Therfore:
$$S-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k-1)}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k+1)}$$
How can I calculate this?

Use the identity $\frac1n=\int_0^1x^{n-1}~{\rm d}x$. This should convert it into a geometric series, which can be summed and then integrated.

You're allowed to separate a series into two subseries if the subseries both converge absolutely.  However, in some series, commuting the terms changes the sum.  What theorem allows separating this series into two subseries?

I have asked this question in $2019$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3190908/what-is-the-value-of-frac11-frac13-frac15-frac17-frac19-frac111-dots

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1 (-1)^{k+1}x^{4k-2}\,dx=\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}x^{4k-2}\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx,$$
where the change of order between sum and integral is justified by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.
Analogously, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(4k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1 (-1)^{k+1}x^{4k}\,dx=\int_0^1 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}x^{4k}\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^4}{1+x^4}\,dx,$$
Thus, we have $$S=1+\int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^2-x^4}{1+x^4}\,dx$$
An antiderivative of the integrand can be found by the standard methods (long division, partial fractions,etc) and is equal to $$\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{2x-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-x$$
Therefore, $$\int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^2-x^4}{1+x^4}\,dx=\dfrac {\arctan(1+\sqrt{2})-\arctan(1-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}-1$$
Using that $\arctan(a)-\arctan(b)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)$ we get $$\int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^2-x^4}{1+x^4}\,dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}-1$$
from where it follows that $$S=1+\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}-1\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

We could rewrite the summation as $\int_0^1 dx + \int_0^1 x^2 dx - \int_0^1 x^4 dx -\int_0^1 x^6 dx + ...$
This could be written as $\int_0^1 1+x^2-x^4-x^6+x^8+x^{10}+... dx$
This could be be simplified by writing these terms as a part of a GP.
We could add and subtract 2 times all the negative parts of the integration.
We get $$\int_0^1 1+x^2+x^4+x^6+... dx - (-2\int_0^1 x^4+x^6+x^{12}+x^{14}... dx)$$
And now we could write the first part of the integration as $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2} dx$$ and similarly we could simplify the final part of the summation by separating each power of consecutive two (sorry for such confusing language), so the final summation becomes $$\int_0^1 x^4+x^{12}+x^{20}+... dx + \int_0^1 x^6+x^{14}+x^{22}+... dx$$.
This can now overall be simplified to $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2} dx + 2( \int_0^1 \frac{x^4}{1-x^8} dx + \int_0^1 \frac{x^6}{1-x^8} dx)$$.
Now this question can be easily solved.
Hope this helps.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Thanks for using MathJax to write your answer. Please note x^n only works as intended when the exponent is a single-character or a call to a backslashed method such as \frac{a}{b}. To get $x^{10}$, you need some curly braces viz.x^{10}.

The last integral is obviously a mistake, unless you meant 1/1.  I'll leave it to you work out what you meant.  perhaps \frac{1}{1-x^2}  etc.
