# Infinite sum $\frac{e^{-a n^2}}{n^2+b^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

I‌ was wondering if the function
\begin{equation}
f(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-a n^2}}{n^2 + b^2},   \qquad\qquad (a,b>0) 
\end{equation}
has a representation in terms of known elementary/special functions (like theta functions etc)?

Comment: $\partial f/\partial a-b^2 f$ is a theta function; solving, you get an integral representation.

Comment: This is $S_{1,0} (b,ab^2 )$ in the preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.01589.pdf. It is stated at the beginning that the second index should be strictly positive but it seems that everything works fine for the case that it is $0$ as well. You can find a representation in therms of the Riemann zeta function and the confluent hypergeometric function, as well as asymptotic expansions in this manuscript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not too difficult to see that we have the differential equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}f(a,b)-b^2f(a,b)=\frac12(1-\vartheta_3(e^{-a})).$$
Using the integrating factor $M(a)=e^{-ab^2}$, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(e^{-tb^2}f(t,b)\right)=\frac12e^{-tb^2}(1-\vartheta_3(e^{-t})),$$
then integrating from $t=0$ to $t=a$, we have
$$e^{-ab^2}f(a,b)-f(0,b)=\frac12\int_0^a e^{-tb^2}(1-\vartheta_3(e^{-t}))dt.$$
Then from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143157/583016), we have
$$f(0,b)=\frac{\pi}{2b}\coth\pi b-\frac1{2b^2},$$
so that
$$f(a,b)=\frac{e^{ab^2}}{2b^2}\left\{\pi b\coth\pi b-1+b^2\int_0^a e^{-tb^2}(1-\vartheta_3(e^{-t}))dt\right\}.$$