# Find the sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist an explicit formula for the sum of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-z^2}?
$$

Comment: Yes (the question is often asked here). See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left/110495#110495).

Comment: That's very nice, many thanks! (The answer is accepted, so I hope it contains a correct proof.)

Comment: Thanks, of course Eric's answer is correct?  Another [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/a-series-expansion-of-cot-pi-z) with links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $(18)$ [on this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cotangent.html) states that $$\pi \cot(\pi z)=\frac{1}{z}+2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2-n^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) handles precisely this question by showing that the Cauchy Principal Value of
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k+z}=\pi\cot(\pi z)
$$
and derives an explicit value for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2-z^2}$ in $(9)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there does.  Of course the sum is not defined if $z$ is a nonzero integer.