# Show $\lim_{x \to0^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n^2x^2+1} = \pi$

Tags: analysis, limits, summation

Show that:

$$\lim_{x \to0^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n^2x^2+1} = \pi$$

Comment: you might find this link helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525/a-series-expansion-of-cot-pi-z
,divide left side by $z^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename $x$ as $\Delta x$. That may help you to see that your limit is $\int_0^\infty{f(x)\,dx}$, where $f(x) = {2\over x^2+1}$. (You should recognize your limit as the limit of a Riemann sum.)

Comment: Now I see, thank you : )

Comment: Great, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2x \over n^{2}x^{2} + 1} = \pi:
     \ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2x \over n^{2}x^{2} + 1}
> &=2\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\bracks{{1 \over x}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1 + \ic/x}\pars{n + 1 - \ic/x}}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\bracks{{1 \over x}
> \,{\Psi\pars{1 + \ic/x} - \Psi\pars{1 - \ic/x}\over
> \pars{1 + \ic/x} - \pars{1 - \ic/x}}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf 6.3.1}$
>   and we used the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
>   ${\bf 6.3.16}$.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2x \over n^{2}x^{2} + 1}
&=2\,\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\Im\Psi\pars{1 + {\ic \over x}}
\end{align}

> With the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
>   ${\bf 6.3.13}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2x \over n^{2}x^{2} + 1}}
> &=\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\bracks{-x + \pi\coth\pars{\pi \over x}}
> =\color{#66f}{\LARGE\pi}
> \end{align}
>   since $\ds{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\coth\pars{\pi \over x} = 1}$.